# volume of a parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determinants and volume of parallelotopes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750/determinants-and-volume-of-parallelotopes)

Can you give me a direction about how to prove that $|det(UVW)|$ is the 3D volume of the parallelogram that defined by $U, V$ and $W$, for $U, V, W \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: The determinant works for rectangular axis-parallel boxes, and is unchanged under the operation "add a multiple of one column to another" (which ought to leave the volume unchanged by geometric considerations). This determines its value for all nontrivial parallelipeds.

Comment: A nit-pick: The 3-dimensional analog of a parallelogram is called a "parallelopiped".

Comment: No, parallelepiped. There's the Greek "epi" in there.

Comment: Not a duplicate as far as I can see. The earlier question asks whether there's a generalization to dimension $>3$; this one seeks a _proof_ for the 3-dimensional case. An answer to one is not the same as an answer to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $a=\frac{V\times W}{\|V\times W)\|}$ is an unit vector orthogonal to the plane spanned by $V$ and $W$. If $\theta$ is the angle between $U$ and $a$, then $U\cdot a=\|U\|\|a\|\cos\theta=\|U\|\cos\theta$ since $a$ is an unit vector. Notice that $a\cdot U$ is the height $h$ of the parallelepiped formed by $U$, $V$ and $W$ with the parallelogram spanned by $V$ and $W$ as the base (It would be easier to understand if you draw a picture), i.e. $$h=a\cdot U.$$ On the other hand, the area $A$ of the base is equal to the area the parallelogram spanned by $V$ and $W$, that is 
$$A=\|V\times W\|.$$
Therefore, the volume of the parallelepiped is given by
$$hA=(U\cdot a)\|V\times W\|=U\cdot (V\times W)$$
since $a=\frac{V\times W}{\|V\times W)\|}$. Now the result follows from
$$\det(U,V,W)=U\cdot(V\times W).$$

Comment: That's answer my question, thanks.

Comment: Is there a elegant way to expand this prove to $\mathbb{R}^n$?