# Geometric Interpretations of the Cramer's Rule

Tags: matrices, vectors, determinant, 3d

> In Cramer's rule when $Δ_x=Δ_y=Δ_z=Δ=0$ what are the possibilities for
>   the three planes (three simultaneous equations in $x,y,z$) to look
>   like? My book says that they can have either infinite solutions or no
>   solutions in such cases. One possibility I can think of is all the
>   planes intersect in a line (i.e. a family of planes). Another is when
>   any two planes are parallel.

- **Is there any third possibility in such a case?**
- **Also, what are the geometric possibilities (in terms of three planes) when $\Delta=0$ but any one or more of $Δ_x,Δ_y,Δ_z$ is non-zero?**

P.S: I know that the $\Delta$ vanishing implies that the normal vectors of the three planes are coplanar.

Comment: Related: [Cramer's rule: geometric interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615021/cramers-rule-geometric-interpretation)