# How do I know that $\det(a,b)$ is the area of parallelogram?

Tags: determinant

Please give an easy explanation, high school level.

Comment: Welcome to math. SE. Have you searched on the web before posting this question ?

Comment: Yes. But still don't understand

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/why-determinant-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-is-the-area-of-a-parallelogram

Comment: The link of Emilio Novati contains a beautiful solution. Another (lenghty but conceptually easy) solution is described here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix_transformations/determinant_depth/v/linear-algebra-determinant-and-area-of-a-parallelogram

Comment: That the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is the signed area of the parallelogram generated by the columns of the matrix ought to be the definition of the determinant. Then the question changes to: how does the usual formula for the determinant follow from this definition? This is an exercise in cutting a parallelogram into triangles.