# How can the area of a parallelogram be show to be equal to the determinant?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am reading  multivariable calculus and it says the area of parallelogram is the same as determinate of 2 by 2 matrix.  I googled and found a nice geometric proof showing the base and height to be the area and it follows logically.  It was Wolfram Mathematics. Then it blurts out the fact that the determinate is the same but now I am not quick enough to see why.  Can someone go in slow motion for me. Since I know how to compute the determinate is there a way to lay this out geometrically to show it is the area of a parallelogram using the stipulation of the definition?

Comment: I remember seeing a really good Khan Academy video on this - maybe you should try and find this? Edit: [found it](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/determinant-depth/v/linear-algebra-determinant-and-area-of-a-parallelogram)

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Area_in_terms_of_Cartesian_coordinates_of_vertices) Wikipedia entry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619212/221811 , or perhaps https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fXZN.png (Mathematics Magazine Vol. 64, No. 5 (Dec., 1991), p. 339)