# Finding the area of a parallelogram with vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors, area, cross-product

I was asked to find the area of the parallelogram formed from these two sides: <-2,1> and <1,3>. 
[image]

How can I find the cross-product if it is not in $\mathbb R^3$?

This picture is  of my work:
[image]

Comment: Hint: the area will be the same as the area of the parallelogram formed by the vectors $\langle -2, 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 1, 3, 0 \rangle$.

Comment: @user744868 So in order to solve I should just add in the zeros

Comment: yes, and $-6-1=-7$, not $<-6,-1>$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner To do this kind of problem can I just find the determinant of the 2x2 matrix and say that is the magnitude? That works this time.

Comment: yes, [the *determinant* of a $2\times2$ matrix gives the magnitude of the parallelogram area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/why-determinant-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-is-the-area-of-a-parallelogram)

Comment: It’s right there in the image that you pasted: the area is equal to the determinant of $[\mathbf a\ \mathbf b]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you could embed the vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ as $(-2,1,0)$ and $(1,3,0)$.

Second of all, the magnitude of the cross-product is $|(0,0,-6-1)|=7.$

Comment: I see - so my mistake was that the discriminant of the 2x2 matrix is the magnitude.

Comment: you can get the magnitude from the *determinant* of the matrix

Comment: whoops:) meant that

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the vectors $\vec a = \langle -2,1\rangle$ and $\vec b= \langle 1,3\rangle$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ via 
$ \vec a = \langle -2,1,0\rangle$ and $\vec b =  \langle 1,3,0\rangle$. Here, I am using the same notations $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ to represent the embedded vectors. 
Then 
$$
|\vec a\times \vec b| = 
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
i & j & k \\ 
-2& 1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\  
\end{array}
\right|  = |-6k-k| = |-7k| = |-7||k| = 7
$$
since $i$, $j$, and $k$ are the standard unit vectors.