# Proving that area of a triangle can be expressed with the determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, area

[image]

I know that this might be a easy problem, but I'm stuck. I don't know how I'm supposed to use the information given in the task (the vectors)to prove that the area is equal to 1/2 det(P). I thought about starting with explaining why det(P) is equal to the area of a parallelogram and so divide by two. But still, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the vectors to do this. Really appreciate some help!

Comment: See answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/why-determinant-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-is-the-area-of-a-parallelogram).

Comment: It is standard that $|\det P[$ is the area of the parallelogram built on $P_0, P_1$ and $P_2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

develop the determinant and see that it coincides with $r1 \times r_2$.

Answer (score 1):

This image should help to show the 'why' connecting the row-vectors and the determinant:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7QGB.png

Comment: Found a more formal proof:
https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/determinants-volumes.html