# What is vector1.x * vector2.y - vector2.x * vector1.y?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

I'm trying to find and so far cant find what is

```
vector1.x * vector2.y - vector2.x * vector1.y
```

When I'm googling most results is about vector multiplication, but in the articles I haven't found this formula yet.

Comment: Do you mean `vector1.x * vector.y - vector.x * vector1.y`? If so, this is a cross product.

Comment: This is horribly unclear.  What sort of objects are `vector1.x` and `vector.y` etc.. What sort of multiplication are you doing?  Are you perhaps trying to multiply *components* of the vectors?  If so... what is causing you trouble here?  That is... for instance if `vector1` happens to be $(4,7)$ for instance, that is with $x$ coordinate $4$ and $y$ coordinate $7$, and `vector` happens to be $(10,20)$ (*these numbers picked arbitrarily just so you can see them show up again later*)... then `vector1.x * vector.y - vector.x * vector.y` would simply be $4\cdot 20 - 10\cdot 20$

Comment: You ask "*What is*"... are you asking for how to evaluate it?  Or are you asking for some physical interpretation of this?  Are you sure you have no typos?  Would you consider using math notation rather than programming notation to make it clearer?  For instance $v_xu_y - u_xu_y$ specifying that $v$ is a vector $v=(v_x,v_y)$ etc...?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, indexes got lost on editing, sorry. I've looked through  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product ,but there formulas always involves angles, so I decided it's something else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why determinant of a 2 by 2 matrix is the area of a parallelogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/why-determinant-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-is-the-area-of-a-parallelogram)

Comment: @Bruice If you look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Mnemonic) you'll see that this is the z-component of the cross product of the two vectors.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks! Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the $z$-component of the cross product of the two vectors.