# determinants by Leibniz formula and areas

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to understand what´s the relation between the definition of the determinants by Leibniz and the calculus of areas. I'm not thinking in proofs like the link I will put below. I want to understand what´s the concept that relates the geometric interpretation of determinant and the definition by Leibniz (that set of permutations). It´s like why that formula created by Leibniz means a "thing"(determinant) that represents an area?
thanks so much for your help,
Alex

[Why determinant of a 2 by 2 matrix is the area of a parallelogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/why-determinant-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-is-the-area-of-a-parallelogram)

Comment: the first answer in the link you provide doesn't do the trick for you? its the same picture in higher dimensions, just more terms

Comment: no:( it´s a proof. i wanna concept. like start from Leibniz definition and arrive in geometric interpretation. what´s the relation between the permutations of Leibniz definition and area calculus

Comment: that picture is the interpretation. its adding and subtracting volumes of hypercubes to get the volume of the hyperparallelopiped. each of the terms in the sum for the leibniz formula corresponds to the volume of a hypercube needed to compute the volume of the hyperparallelopiped

Comment: the point is that i dont understand why it works. i understood the process

Comment: My [video](https://youtu.be/9IswLDsEWFk) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks so much ☺️ Ur class is Very good 