# How to prove $\gcd(m, n) = \gcd(-m, n)?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Beginner question here:

For a quiz on Elementary Number Theory in my Discrete Math course I was asked to prove if $\gcd(m, n) = \gcd(-m, n)$. I used the Euclidean Algorithm to show that the two expressions simplify to $\gcd(n,\ m\pmod{n})$ and $\gcd(n,\ -m\pmod{n})$ respectively. Then I went on to show (well I tried... but that's another question) that $-m\pmod{n} = m\pmod{n}$.

If I was able to do this correctly, does this approach result in a valid proof? If not, is there a different/better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: definition is enough!

Comment: Note that $-1 \equiv 3 (mod 4)$ while $1 \equiv 1 (mod 4)$. So, $-m$ (mod n) $\neq$ $m$ (mod n) in general.

Comment: It's not generally true that for two non-zero integers $m,n$ the equivalence $m \equiv -m \mod n$ holds. Try 1 and 3 for example.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even realize that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are few proofs, by gcd definition, [general Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242), and unimodularity.

---

$d\,|\,m,n\!\iff d\,|\,{-}m,n,\,$ so $\,m,n\,$ and $\: -m,n\,$ have the same set $S$ of common divisors $\,d\,$ so the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S),\,$ same as in the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) of $\:\!\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a\bmod b,b)$

---

**Alternatively** it's a special case  $\,\color{#c00}k=-1\,$ in $\,(\color{#c00}km,n)\,=\,(\color{#c00}{(k,n)}\:\!m,n)\,$

**Proof** $\ \ \,(km,n)\,=\,(km,n(m,1))\,=\,(km,nm,n)\,=\,((k,n)m,n)$

The above proof uses only basic gcd laws (associative, commutative, distributive) - [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b/20904#20904). Euclid's Lemma is the case: $\,\color{#c00}{(k,n) =  1}\,\Rightarrow\,(km,\:n)\,=\,(\color{#c00}{ 1}m,\:n)$

---

**Or** let $\,a,b,c,d=-1,0,0,1\,$  in [$\,\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(am\!+\!bn,cm\!+\!dn)\,$ if $\,ad\!-\!bc = \pm1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52373/242)

---

**Corollary** $\ \gcd(|m|,|n|) = \gcd(m,n),\ $ by $\,|x| = \pm x\ $ (or $\ d\mid |x|\!\iff d\mid x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is simply to observe that $m$ and $-m$ have exactly the same divisors: $d\mid m$ iff there is an integer $k$ such that $m=kd$ iff $-m=(-k)d$ iff $d\mid -m$, and $-k$ is an integer iff $k$ is an integer. Thus, the common divisors of $m$ and $n$ are exactly the same as the common divisors of $-m$ and $n$, and hence $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(-m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

So here is really a simple answer that should follow by definition:

Let $d = \gcd(m, n)$ and $d' = \gcd(-m,n)$. By definition of a gcd, $d| m,n$. So, $d|-m,n$. Hence, $d|d'$. Similarly one can show that $d'|d$. Then $d= \pm d'$. But, GCDs in $\mathbb{Z}$ are positive. So, $d = d'$, because d, d' are both positive.

Comment: Actually, depending on how you choose to define the GCD, the assertion $d|d'$ may/may not be trivial.

Comment: In either case, Bill and Brian have better answers. So, take a look at their answers.