# Can we find the GCD of a positive and negative number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to evaluate whether or not $\gcd(p,q) = \gcd(-p,q)$ for non-zero integers $p$ and $q$.

I was wondering if it's possible to find $\gcd(-p,q)$.

If so, this statement should be true, correct?

Comment: If we define $\gcd(a,b)$, where $a$ and/or $b$ may be negative, in the usual way (*greatest* common divisor), then it is not hard to show directly from the definition that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: The prescription Andre gives is also consistent with Bezout's theorem, since if $ap+bq=gcd(p,q)$ then $(-a)(-p)+bq=gcd(p,q)$ as well.

Comment: [Check my animated answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270017/2917832).

Comment: Oh! yes. The word "greatest" .

Comment: Easy answer.  Sign doesn't matter $\gcd(\pm a, \pm b) = \gcd(a,b)$.  If you feel weird about that just keep in mind if $n|m$ so $m = kn$ then $-n|m$ ans $m = (-k)(-n)$ and $n|-m$ as $-m = (-k)n$.

Comment: See my answer below, if there is no notion of "greatest" in your ring, then do as @fleablood says.  Say that your ring "has $\gcd$'s" which means each $\gcd(a,b)$ is only unique up to mulplication by a unit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\gcd(m, n) = \gcd(-m, n)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92434/how-to-prove-gcdm-n-gcd-m-n)

Answer (score 15):

Somebody has [a good proof on proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_for_Negative_Integers) which makes sense to me.
It shows that
$$
\gcd\{a,b\}=\gcd\{|a|,b\}=\gcd\{a,|b|\}=\gcd\{|a|,|b|\} .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Define the $\gcd$ like a categorial universal property.  This avoids having to make use of an ordering $\leq$ on the ring in which you desire a $\gcd$.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.

Define $\gcd(a,b)$ to be any element $d \in R$ such that $d \mid a, b$ and if $e \mid a,b$ then $e \mid d$.

Then when $R = \Bbb{Z}$, $\gcd(-n, m),$ for $n,m \gt 0$ always has two elements, but they are "isomorphic" meaning they're the same upto a unit factor: $d = (-1)d'$.

So simply define $\gcd$ as you do "product" in a category i.e. there can be many products of objects $A, B$ but they are all isomorphic.