# If $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $ad-bc = 1$, why are $(ax+by)$ and $(cx+dy)$ relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving two gcd's equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52373/proving-two-gcds-equal)

Let $a,b,c,d,x,y$ be integers with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
=
ad-bc = 1.
$$
I have come across the assertion that $(ax+by)$ and $(cx+dy)$ must be relatively prime, but I don't see why.

$gcd(x,y)=1$ means there are $C,D$ such that
$$Cx+Dy=1$$

I want to find $A,B$ such that
$$A(ax+by) + B(cx+dy) = 1.$$

I've tried expanding and regrouping the terms in the LHS in different ways to try to use what I've got, but I'm stuck.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: *Exact* duplicate of said question. Answers are duplicates too.

Answer (score 3):

In other words, given $C,D$ you want to solve the following for $A,B$.

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} C \\ D \end{pmatrix}$$

Since $\det = ad-cb=1$ the inverse will have integer components. If we multiply by the inverse,

$$\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}d & -c \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C \\ D \end{pmatrix}.$$

Note this proves $\gcd(x,y)$ is invariant under the action of the special linear group $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
ax+by\\
cx+dy
\end{vmatrix}$$

Thus

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}^{-1} \begin{vmatrix}
ax+by\\
cx+dy
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
ax+by\\
cx+dy
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now, replace this in $Ax+By=1$ and you get your desired result.