# Help with GCD Coprime Proof

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a,b,c,d,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1, \gcd(a,c) = 1, \gcd(d,b) = 1, \gcd(d,c) = 1, \gcd(x,y) = 1$.

**Prove $\gcd(ax+by,cx+dy) = 1$**

I'm trying to figure out how I can use these facts that parts of this formula $ax+by$ and $cx+dy$ are coprime to say that their linear combination must also be coprime. But I'm not sure how to formalize this since I'm dealing with sums rather than products.

Comment: This is true instead https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784008/399263, see jjagmath counterexample.

Comment: Thanks very much @zwim! That's actually exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample: $a=b=c=d=x=y=1$