# Why is the determinant a homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show $\det(AB) =\det(A)\det(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-detab-deta-detb)

Consider the map $q:\operatorname{GL}(n,R)→R^*$ given by $q(A)=\det(A)$. I know that $$q(AB)=q(A)q(B)=\det(A)\det(B)$$ does not hold if determinants of $A$ and $B$ are not unity. I would like to know why the map is homomorphic?

Comment: the multiplicativity of the determinant holds independently of any other conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups

Comment: What do you mean by $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A)*\text{det}(B)$ [doesn't hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinants#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups)?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60284/660).

Comment: @Pierre: Should we close as a duplicate, then?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I think so.

Answer (score 5):

It is a homomorphism because you are incorrect that $\det(AB)\neq\det(A)\det(B)$ unless $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are 1; in fact the statement that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ is always true for matrices over any commutative ring.

This is something I've always just thought, but I had a surprising amount of difficulty coming up with a reference for it, and I couldn't think of a way of proving the general statement myself, which is off-putting. At any rate, [here is one proof](http://math.fontein.de/2010/11/10/multiplicity-of-the-determinant/), which shows that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ holds for matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, then argues that this implies it is true for matrices over any ring $R$ because the determinant is an integer polynomial in the entries of a matrix and we can embed the polynomial ring in $n^2$ variables over $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

Also, note that one says that a map "is a homomorphism", *not* "is homomorphic".

Comment: Anyone tried looking at some of Dieudonne's work?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're referring to, Geoff.