# Determinant of symmetrical factorized matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ with $b_{ij} = t^{i-j}\cdot a_{ij}$. Prove $\det(A) = \det(B)$.

I first thought of induction. I can easily prove this for $n \le 2$.

My induction hypothesis: $\det(A) = \det(B)$ with $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Induction step: $\det(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_{ij} \cdot (-1)^{i+j} \cdot \det(B_{ij})\overset{IH}{=} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} t^{i-j} a_{ij} \cdot (-1)^{i+j} \cdot \det(A_{ij})$

So far, so good, but I can't seem to get rid of the exponentiation of $t$. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure that your induction step is valid. You replace $\det(B_{ij})$ with $\det(A_{ij})$ simply because these are $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices. But the indexing on the cofactors does not preserve the pattern of $i-j$ as the exponent on $t$.

Comment: That never occurred to me but you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}t \\ & t^2\\ & & \ddots\\ & & & t^n\end{bmatrix}
$$
(and zeroes off-diagonal). 
Then 
$$
B=TAT^{-1},
$$
so $\det B=\det T\; \det A\;(\det T)^{-1}=\det A$.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure.  $\phantom{XXXX}$

Answer (score 2):

In my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-detab-deta-detb/60383#60383) I give the permutations-based definition of the determinant, which is equivalent to all other standard definitions.

This result is almost immediate using the permutations-based definition.

$$
\begin{align}
\det(B)  & = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^nB_{i,\sigma(i)}\\
&  = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^n(t^{i-\sigma(i)}A_{i,\sigma(i)})\\
&  = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^nt^{i-\sigma(i)}\prod_{i=1}^nA_{i,\sigma(i)}\\
\end{align}
$$

And $\prod_{i=1}^nt^{i-\sigma(i)}=1$, since the sum over all $i$ gives $t^{\binom{n+1}{2}-\binom{n+1}{2}}=t^0=1$. So

$$
\begin{align}
\det(B)  & = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^nA_{i,\sigma(i)}\\
&= \det(A)
\end{align}
$$