# Is $\det(AB) =\det(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A, B$ be square matrices. I am having trouble proving if
$$ \det(AB) = \det(BA) $$ is right or wrong. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ assumed to be square matrices, or just any rectangular matrices such that the product is square?

Comment: @DanielFischer the matrices are square, I added it to the question

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm curious why the doubt: since both $AB$ and $BA$ appear to be defined, they are required to be square (unless there is some obscure branch of algebra where it is possible otherwise? I can't imagine what that would be)

Comment: @EuroMicelli If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m\times n$, then $AB$ is $n\times n$ and $BA$ is $m\times m$, so they're both square, but of possibly different sizes, whereas $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily square.

Comment: Note that this can fail if the sizes are different: the smaller matrix can be invertible, but the bigger one never can be: $rank(AB) \leq min(rank(A), rank(B))$.

Comment: Oh, duh. Sorry. I shouldn't be posting late at night. I stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For square matrices $A, B$:$$\det(AB) = \det A \cdot \det B = \det B\cdot\det A = \det(BA)$$

To better understand why $\det(AB) = \det A \cdot \det B$, see [this post:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-detab-deta-detb)

Answer (score 13):

Yes if $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices with the same size then

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$

Answer (score 6):

Sketch of proof: You're probably overthinking this because matrices don't commute in general. *It turns out it's irrelevant in this case.* The key fact here is that even though matrices do not in general commute, the determinant is a real valued function. So det(A) and det(B) are real numbers and multiplication of real numbers is commutative regardless of how they're derived. So det(A)det(B) = det(B)det(A) regardless of whether or not AB=BA.So if A and B are square matrices, the result follows from the fact det (AB) = det (A) det(B).

You should be able to finish the proof,no problem now.