# Square root of determinant equals determinant of square root?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is it true that for a real-valued positive definite matrix $X$, $\sqrt{\det(X)} = \det(X^{1/2})$?

I know that this is indeed true for the $2 \times 2$ case but I haven't been able to find the answer or prove it myself for larger $X$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: How are you defining $X^{1/2}$? In general, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. So if $X^{1/2}\cdot X^{1/2}=X$ then $(\det(X^{1/2}))^2=\det(X)$.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call $Y = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Then $\det X = \det (Y^2) = (\det Y)^2$, so $\sqrt{\det X} = |\det Y|$. If $Y$ is positive definite, then $|\det Y| = \det Y$, and so we are done.

Comment: I appreciate all of the answers but this one was first. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean by $X^{1/2}$ a matrix $Y$ such that $Y^2=X$, in which case
$$\begin{align}
\det Y^2=\det X & \implies (\det Y)^2=X\\
& \implies \det Y=\pm\sqrt{\det X)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

If you know that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, then this is immediate, taking $A=B=X^{1/2}$. If you don't know that, there are several proofs suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb).