# Prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about any row or column, in which determinants are defined recursively.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and columns $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $A({i_1,\dots,i_s}|{j_1,\dots,j_t})$.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, we see $A({1,2,\dots,n}|{1,2,\dots,n})$ as a "zero-by-zero matrix" for the sake of convenience.

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. The determinant of $A$, $\det {(A)}$ is defined as follows:
$$
\det {(A)}
=
\begin{cases}
    [A]_{1,1},
        & n = 1;    \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}},
        & n \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$

It should be noted that we can simply write
$$
\det {(A)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}
$$
if we define the determinant of a "zero-by-zero matrix" to be $1$.

---

Here are two important theorems, from which a lot of facts about determinants can be easily deduced.

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and that $j$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Then
$$
\det {(A)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}}.
$$

**Theorem 2.** Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and that $i$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Then
$$
\det {(A)} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}}.
$$

How does one prove the two theorems with the aforementioned definition of determinants?

Comment: Related: [Proving generalized form of Laplace expansion along a row - determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331303).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of useful notation. Suppose that $i$, $j$ are two integers. We define
$$
\rho(i, j)
= \begin{cases}
        0, & i < j;    \\
        1, & i \geq j.
    \end{cases}
$$

---

**Proof of Theorem 1.** Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For **any** $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and for **any** positive integer $j$ less than or equal to $n$,
> $$
> \det {(A)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}}.
> $$

We will prove that $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is true by definition.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true (which I leave as an exercise).

Suppose that $P(m-1)$ is true. Our goal is to prove that $P(m)$ is true.

Let $A$ be an $m \times m$ matrix. Let $j$ be a positive integer less than or equal to $m$. If $j = 1$, it is just the definition. If $j > 1$, we first expand the determinant of $A$ about the first column, and then apply the hypothesis to every $(m - 1) \times (m - 1)$ submatrix:
$$
\begin{aligned}
   & \det {(A)}
   \\
= {} &
\sum_{i = 1}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{i = 1}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1}
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq m \\ \ell \neq i}} {
(-1)^{(\ell - \rho(\ell, i)) + (j - 1)}
    [A]_{\ell,j} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{i = 1}^{m} {
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq m \\ \ell \neq i}} {
(-1)^{(\ell - \rho(\ell, i)) + (j - 1)}
(-1)^{i+1}
    [A]_{i,1} [A]_{\ell,j} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} {
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq m    \\ i \neq \ell}} {
(-1)^{(\ell - \rho(\ell, i)) + (j - 1)}
(-1)^{i+1}
    [A]_{i,1} [A]_{\ell,j} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} {
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq m    \\ i \neq \ell}} {
(-1)^{\ell} (-1)^{\rho(\ell, i)} (-1)^{i} (-1)^{j}
    [A]_{i,1} [A]_{\ell,j} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} {
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq m    \\ i \neq \ell}} {
(-1)^{\ell + j} (-1)^{i - \rho(i, \ell) + 1}
    [A]_{i,1} [A]_{\ell,j} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} {(-1)^{\ell + j} [A]_{\ell,j}
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq m    \\ i \neq \ell}} {
(-1)^{i - \rho(i, \ell) + 1}
    [A]_{i,1} \det {(A({i,\ell}|{1,j}))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} {(-1)^{\ell + j} [A]_{\ell,j}
\det {(A(\ell|j))}
}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here are two useful tips:

- $[A]_{\ell,j}$ is the $(\ell - \rho(\ell, i), j-1)$-entry of $A(i|1)$;
- $[A]_{i,1}$ is the $(i - \rho(i, \ell), 1)$-entry of $A(\ell|j)$.

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

---

**Proof of Theorem 2.** Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For **any** $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and for **any** positive integer $i$ less than or equal to $n$,
> $$
> \det {(A)} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}}.
> $$

We will prove that $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is true by definition.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true (which I leave as an exercise).

Suppose that $P(m-1)$ is true. Our goal is to prove that $P(m)$ is true.

Let $A$ be an $m \times m$ matrix. Let $i$ be a positive integer less than or equal to $m$. We first expand the determinant of $A$ about the first column, and then apply the hypothesis to every $(m - 1) \times (m - 1)$ submatrix except $A(i|1)$ (in which we write $f = (-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}$ for brevity):
$$
\begin{aligned}
        & \det {(A)}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m \\k \neq i}}
{(-1)^{k+1} [A]_{k,1} \det {(A(k|1))}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m \\k \neq i}}
{(-1)^{k+1} [A]_{k,1}
\sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{(-1)^{i - \rho(i,k) + j - 1}
    [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(k,i|1,j))}}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m \\k \neq i}}
{\sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{(-1)^{k+1} [A]_{k,1}
(-1)^{i - \rho(i,k) + j - 1}
    [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(k,i|1,j))}}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{\sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m    \\k \neq i}}
{(-1)^{k+1} [A]_{k,1}
    (-1)^{i - \rho(i,k) + j - 1}
        [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(k,i|1,j))}}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{\sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m    \\k \neq i}}
{(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j}
    (-1)^{k - \rho(k,i) + 1}
        [A]_{k,1} \det {(A(k,i|1,j))}}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j}
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq m     \\k \neq i}}
{(-1)^{k - \rho(k,i) + 1}
        [A]_{k,1} \det {(A(k,i|1,j))}}}
\\
= {} &
f + \sum_{j = 2}^{m}
{(-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here are two useful tips (in which $k \neq i$ and $j \neq 1$):

- $[A]_{i,j}$ is the $(i - \rho(i, k), j-1)$-entry of $A(k|1)$;
- $[A]_{k,1}$ is the $(k - \rho(k, i), 1)$-entry of $A(i|j)$.

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about *any* row, one can first prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about *the first* row. Then one can just prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about any *row*, as one can prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about any *column*. (I feel that I have repeated so many words; I would like some advice on reduce repetition....)

---

Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For **any** $n \times n$ matrix $A$,
> $$
> \det {(A)} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{1+j} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(1|j))}}.
> $$

We will prove that $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is true by definition.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true (which I leave as an exercise).

Suppose that $P(m-1)$ is true. Our goal is to prove that $P(m)$ is true.

Let $A$ be an $m \times m$ matrix. We first expand the determinant of $A$ about the first column, and then apply the hypothesis to every $(m - 1) \times (m - 1)$ submatrix except $A(1|1)$ (in which we write $f = (-1)^{1+1} [A]_{1,1} \det {(A(1|1))}$ for brevity):
$$
\begin{aligned}
        & \det {(A)} \\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1}
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{1+j-1} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(i,1|1,j))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1}
(-1)^{1+j-1} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(i,1|1,j))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1}
(-1)^{1+j-1} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(i,1|1,j))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{1+j} [A]_{1,j}
(-1)^{i-1+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i,1|1,j))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{1+j} [A]_{1,j}
\sum_{i = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{i-1+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i,1|1,j))}
}
}
\\
= {} &
f
+
\sum_{j = 2}^{m} {
(-1)^{1+j} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(1|j))}
}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here are two useful tips (in which $k \neq 1$ and $j \neq 1$):

- $[A]_{1,j}$ is the $(1, j-1)$-entry of $A(k|1)$;
- $[A]_{k,1}$ is the $(k-1, 1)$-entry of $A(1|j)$.

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.