# Prove the generalized Laplace expansion.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and columns $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $A({i_1,\dots,i_s}|{j_1,\dots,j_t})$.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, we see $A({1,2,\dots,n}|{1,2,\dots,n})$ as a "zero-by-zero matrix" for the sake of convenience.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing all rows **other than** rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and all columns **other than** $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $\displaystyle A\binom{i_1,\dots,i_s}{j_1,\dots,j_t}$.

> *Example.* Let
> $$ A =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
> 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
> 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
> 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
> \end{bmatrix}.$$
> Then
> $$A({1,2}|{3}) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 11 & 12 & 14 & 15 \\
> 16 & 17 & 19 & 20 \\
> \end{bmatrix},$$
> and
> $$A\binom{1,2}{3} = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3 \\
> 8 \\
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. The determinant of $A$, $\det {(A)}$ is defined as follows:
$$ \det {(A)}
=
\begin{cases}
    [A]_{1,1},
        & n = 1;    \\
    \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}},
        & n \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$

It should be noted that we can simply write
$$
\det {(A)} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}
$$
if we define the determinant of a "zero-by-zero matrix" to be $1$.

---

Here are the generalized Laplace expansions, one with respect to columns and the other with respect to rows.

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_k$ are distinct positive integers less than or equal to $n$, and that $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
    {\det {\left(
            A\binom{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k}
            {j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k}
            \right)}}
    (-1)^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k
        + j_1 + j_2 + \dots + j_k}
    \det {(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Theorem 2.** Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_k$ are distinct positive integers less than or equal to $n$, and that $i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k \leq n}
    {\det {\left(
            A\binom{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k}
            {j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k}
            \right)}}
    (-1)^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k
        + j_1 + j_2 + \dots + j_k}
    \det {(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}.
\end{aligned}
$$

How does one prove the two theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier if it is first proved that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about any row or column; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4712271) for the details.

I will use the $\rho$-notation which is defined in the above answer.

I will prove only the first theorem; the proof of the second one is very similar to that of the first one, which I leave as an exercise.

---

Let the proposition $P(k)$ be as follows:

> For **any** $n \times n$ matrix (in which $n \geq k$) and for any $k$ distinct integers $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_k$ less than or equal to $n$ (in which $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$),
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
>     \det {(A)}
>     = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
>     {\det {\left(
>             A\binom{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k}
>             {j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k}
>             \right)}}
>     (-1)^{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k
>         + j_1 + j_2 + \dots + j_k}
>     \det {(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}.
> \end{aligned}
> $$

We will prove that $P(k)$ is true for $k = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

$P(1)$ is true, because the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about any column.

Suppose that $P(k-1)$ is true. Our goal is to prove that $P(k)$ is true.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, with $n \geq k$. Let $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_k$ be any $k$ distinct integers less than or equal to $n$, with $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \det {(A)}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{d_1 = 1}^{n}
{[A]_{d_1,j_1}
(-1)^{d_1 + j_1}
\det {(A(d_1|j_1))}}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{d_1 = 1}^{n}
{[A]_{d_1,j_1}
(-1)^{d_1 + j_1}}
\sum_{\substack{
1 \leq d_2 < \dots < d_k \leq n \\
        d_1 \neq d_2,\dots,d_k
    }}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{d_2, \dots, d_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
(-1)^{d_2 - \rho(d_2, d_1) + \dots
    + d_k - \rho(d_k, d_1)
    + j_2 + \dots + j_k - (k - 1)}
\det
{(A({d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\substack{
1 \leq d_1 \leq n               \\
1 \leq d_2 < \dots < d_k \leq n \\
        d_1 \neq d_2,\dots,d_k
    }}
{[A]_{d_1,j_1}
(-1)^{d_1 + j_1}}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{d_2, \dots, d_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
(-1)^{d_2 - \rho(d_2, d_1) + \dots
    + d_k - \rho(d_k, d_1)
    + j_2 + \dots + j_k - (k - 1)}
\det
{(A({d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\substack{
1 \leq d_1 \leq n               \\
1 \leq d_2 < \dots < d_k \leq n \\
        d_1 \neq d_2,\dots,d_k
    }}
(-1)^{
    (d_1 + \dots + d_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
    + (\rho(d_1, d_2) + \dots + \rho(d_1, d_k))
    - 2(k-1)
}
[A]_{d_1,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{d_2, \dots, d_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\det
{(A({d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{\substack{
1 \leq d_1 \leq n               \\
1 \leq d_2 < \dots < d_k \leq n \\
        d_1 \neq d_2,\dots,d_k
    }}
(-1)^{
    (d_1 + \dots + d_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
    + (\rho(d_1, d_2) + \dots + \rho(d_1, d_k))
}
[A]_{d_1,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{d_2, \dots, d_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\det
{(A({d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
\sum_{\substack{
    1 \leq s \leq k\\
    d_1 = i_s \\
    d_r = i_{r-1}, \ 2 \leq r \leq s \\
    d_r = i_{r}, \ r > s \\
    }}
(-1)^{
    (d_1 + \dots + d_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
    + (\rho(d_1, d_2) + \dots + \rho(d_1, d_k))
}
[A]_{d_1,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{d_2, \dots, d_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\det
{(A({d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
\sum_{1 \leq s \leq k}
(-1)^{
    (i_1 + \dots + i_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
    + (s-1)
}
[A]_{i_s,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{i_1,\dots,i_{s-1},i_{s+1},\dots,i_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\det
{(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
\left(
(-1)^{s-1}
\sum_{1 \leq s \leq k}
[A]_{i_s,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{i_1,\dots,i_{s-1},i_{s+1},\dots,i_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\right)
(-1)^{
    (i_1 + \dots + i_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
}
\det
{(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
\left(
(-1)^{s+1}
\sum_{1 \leq s \leq k}
[A]_{i_s,j_1}
{\det {\left(
        A\binom{i_1,\dots,i_{s-1},i_{s+1},\dots,i_k}{j_2, \dots, j_k}
        \right)}}
\right)
(-1)^{
    (i_1 + \dots + i_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
}
\det
{(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}
\\
= {} &
\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n}
{
\det {\left(
    A\binom{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k}
    {j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k}
    \right)}
}
(-1)^{
    (i_1 + \dots + i_k) + (j_1 + \dots + j_k)
}
\det
{(A({i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}|{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_k}))}.
\end{aligned}
$$

We have used the hypothesis in the second equality.

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(k)$ is true for $k = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Note that the proof uses nothing more than the usual Laplace expansion.