# Prove that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first two columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $m$, and that $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ are distinct integers less than or equal to $n$. The matrix obtained from $A$ by removing rows $i_1$, $i_2$, $\dots$, $i_s$ and columns $j_1$, $j_2$, $\dots$, $j_t$ is denoted as $A({i_1,\dots,i_s}|{j_1,\dots,j_t})$.

*Determinants are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712270/prove-that-the-determinant-of-a-square-matrix-can-be-computed-by-expansion-about).*

I will prove, by directly appealing to the definition, that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ (in which $n > 2$).

---

Note that the result is simply an easy corollary of [the generalized Laplace expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713308/prove-the-generalized-laplace-expansion). It will be useful in *a* proof of [the alternating property of $\det$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721453) and in *a* proof of [the antisymmetric property of $\det$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $i$, $j$ are two integers. Define
$$
\rho(i, j)
= \begin{cases}
        0, & i < j;    \\
        1, & i \geq j.
    \end{cases}
$$

Note that $[A]_{d_2, 2}$ is the $(d_2 - \rho(d_2, d_1), 1)$-entry of $A(d_1|1)$, in which $d_2 \neq d_1$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(A)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{d_1 = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{d_1+1} [A]_{d_1,1}
    \det {(A(d_1|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{d_1 = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{d_1+1} [A]_{d_1,1}
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_2 \leq n     \\d_2 \neq d_1}}
    {(-1)^{d_2 - \rho(d_2,d_1) + 1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{d_1 = 1}^{n}
    {\sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_2 \leq n    \\d_2 \neq d_1}}
    {(-1)^{d_1+1} [A]_{d_1,1}
        (-1)^{d_2 - \rho(d_2,d_1) + 1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_1,d_2 \leq n \\d_1 \neq d_2}}
    {(-1)^{d_1+1} [A]_{d_1,1}
        (-1)^{d_2 - \rho(d_2,d_1) + 1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_1,d_2 \leq n \\d_1 \neq d_2}}
    {(-1)^{\rho(d_1,d_2)}
            [A]_{d_1,1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        (-1)^{d_1+d_2+1+2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_1,d_2 \leq n \\d_1 < d_2}}
    {(-1)^{\rho(d_1,d_2)}
            [A]_{d_1,1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        (-1)^{d_1+d_2+1+2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}
    \\
            &
    +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq d_1,d_2 \leq n \\d_1 > d_2}}
    {(-1)^{\rho(d_1,d_2)}
            [A]_{d_1,1} [A]_{d_2,2}
        (-1)^{d_1+d_2+1+2}
        \det {(A(d_1,d_2|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i,k \leq n     \\i < k}}
    {(-1)^{\rho(i,k)}
            [A]_{i,1} [A]_{k,2}
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
            &
    +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k,i \leq n     \\k > i}}
    {(-1)^{\rho(k,i)}
            [A]_{k,1} [A]_{i,2}
        (-1)^{k+i+1+2}
        \det {(A(k,i|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {([A]_{i,1} [A]_{k,2} - [A]_{k,1} [A]_{i,2})\,
    (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
    \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}.
\end{aligned}
$$