# Prove the antisymmetric property of the function $\det$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Suppose $A$ is a matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $m \times 1$ matrices. Then $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i, j)$-entry is equal to $[a_j]_{i,1}$. The piece of notation allows one to display a matrix using its columns.

*Determinants are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712270/prove-that-the-determinant-of-a-square-matrix-can-be-computed-by-expansion-about).*

How does one prove the antisymmetric property?

> Suppose that $q$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Suppose that $p$ is a positive integer less than $q$. Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Then
> $$ \det
> {[a_1, \dots, \overset{\text{column}\,p}{a_q}, \dots,
>     \overset{\text{column}\,q}{a_p}, \dots, a_n]}
> = -\det {[\dots, a_p, \dots, a_q, \dots]}. $$

Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For any $n \times 1$ matrices $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$, any positive integer $q$ less than or equal to $n$, any positive integer $p$ less than $q$,
> $$ \det
> {[a_1, \dots, \overset{\text{column}\,p}{a_q}, \dots,
>     \overset{\text{column}\,q}{a_p}, \dots, a_n]}
> = -\det {[\dots, a_p, \dots, a_q, \dots]}. $$

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true:
$$
\det {\begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d \\
\end{bmatrix}}
= ad - bc
= -(cb - da)
= -\det {\begin{bmatrix}
    c & a \\
    d & b \\
\end{bmatrix}}.
$$

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I need to show that $P(n)$ is true.

I know that it suffices to prove that swapping two *adjacent* columns changes the sign. Suppose that one has proved it. Suppose that $p < q$. It can be shown that swapping columns $p$ and $q$ amounts to swapping two adjacent columns $2(q - p) - 1$ times, which ultimately changes the sign:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    0\colon & \dots, p, p+1, p+2, \dots, q-1, q, \dots \\
    1\colon & \dots, p+1, p, p+2, \dots, q-1, q, \dots \\
    {} & \vdots \\
    q-p\colon & \dots, p+1, p+2, \dots, q-1, q, p, \dots \\
    q-p+1\colon & \dots, p+1, p+2, \dots, q, q-1, p, \dots \\
    {} & \vdots \\
    q-p+(q-p+1)\colon & \dots, q, p+1, p+2, \dots, q-1, p, \dots \\
\end{aligned}
$$

However, I do not know how to prove the special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is direct, which is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about *any* column.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Choose a positive integer $q$ less than or equal to $n$. Choose a positive integer $q$ less than $p$. Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A = [\dots, a_p, \dots, a_q, \dots], \\
& B = [\dots, a_q, \dots, a_p, \dots],
\end{aligned}
$$
in which $B$ is obtained from $A$ by interchanging the location of columns $p$ and $q$.

**Choose a positive integer $u$ less than or equal to $n$ so that $u \neq p$ and that $u \neq q$.** Note that $B(i|u)$ can be seen as the matrix obtained from $A(i|u)$ by interchanging the location of two columns (for $i = 1$, $2$, $\dots$, $n$). By the hypothesis, $\det {(B(i|u))} = -\det {(A(i|u))}$. Note that $[B]_{i,u} = [A]_{i,u}$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(B)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+u} [B]_{i,u} \det {(B(i|u))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+u} [A]_{i,u} (-\det {(A(i|u))})}
    \\
    = {} &
    {-\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+u} [A]_{i,u} \det {(A(i|u))}}}
    \\
    = {} & {-\det {(A)}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.

---

Note that the proof works with any two columns, which are not necessarily adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

The proof uses the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first two columns:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4721053) is a proof, which just uses the definition.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Let $A = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

**As is mentioned in the description of the question, it suffices to prove that swapping two *adjacent* columns changes the sign.**

Let $p$ be a positive integer less than $n$. Put $q = p + 1$. Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by interchanging the location of columns $p$ and $q$. Then $[A]_{i,p} = [B]_{i,p+1}$, $[A]_{i+1,p} = [B]_{i,p}$, and for $\ell \neq p, p+1$, $[A]_{i,\ell} = [B]_{i,\ell}$.

Suppose first that $p > 1$. Then $B(i|1)$ can be seen as the square matrix obtained from $A(i|1)$ by interchanging the location of columns $p-1$, $p$. By the hypothesis, $\det {(B(i|1))} = -\det {(A(i|1))}$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(B)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [B]_{i,1} \det {(B(i|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} (-\det {(A(i|1))})}
    \\
    = {} &
    {-\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}}
    \\
    = {} & {-\det {(A)}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Suppose then that $p = 1$. The definition does not work as it just did; it will work differently. Note that $A(i,k|1,2) = B(i,k|1,2)$ for distinct integers $i$, $k$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(B)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [B]_{i,1} & [B]_{i,2} \\
                [B]_{k,1} & [B]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(B(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,2} & [A]_{i,1} \\
                [A]_{k,2} & [A]_{k,1} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\left(-\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }\right)
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} & {-\det {(A)}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first *row*.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Let $A = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

**As is mentioned in the description of the question, it suffices to prove that swapping two *adjacent* columns changes the sign.**

Let $p$ be a positive integer less than $n$. Put $q = p + 1$. Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by interchanging the location of columns $p$ and $q$. Then $[A]_{i,p} = [B]_{i,p+1}$, $[A]_{i+1,p} = [B]_{i,p}$, and for $\ell \neq p, p+1$, $[A]_{i,\ell} = [B]_{i,\ell}$.

Note that $A(1|p) = B(1|p+1)$ and that $A(1|p+1) = B(1|p)$. Note that for $\ell \neq p, p+1$, $B(1|\ell)$ can be seen as the square matrix obtained from $A(1|\ell)$ by interchanging the location of two (adjacent) columns. By the hypothesis, $\det {(B(1|\ell))} = -\det {(A(1|\ell))}$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(B)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [B]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (-1)^{1 + p} [B]_{1,p} \det {(B(1|p))}
    + (-1)^{1 + p+1} [B]_{1,p+1} \det {(B(1|p+1))}
    \\
    & +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq p, p+1}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [B]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p+1} \det {(A(1|p+1))}
    + (-1)^{1 + p+1} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    \\
    & +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq p, p+1}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} (-\det {(A(1|k))})}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    {-(-1)^{1 + p+1}} [A]_{1,p+1} \det {(A(1|p+1))}
    - (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    \\
    & -
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq p, p+1}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    {-\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}}
    \\
    = {} & {-\det {(A)}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.