# Prove the multilinear property of the function $\det$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

*Determinants are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712270/prove-that-the-determinant-of-a-square-matrix-can-be-computed-by-expansion-about).*

Suppose $A$ is a matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $m \times 1$ matrices. Then $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i, j)$-entry is equal to $[a_j]_{i,1}$. The piece of notation allows one to display a matrix using its columns.

How does one prove the multilinear property?

> Suppose that $j$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Suppose that $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{j+1}$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Suppose that $x$, $y$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Suppose that $s$, $t$ are numbers. Then
> $$ \begin{aligned}
>             & \det
>         {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, \overset{\text{column}\,j}{sx + ty},
>                     a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     \\
>     = {} &
>     s
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     +
>     t
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}.
> \end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is indirect, which is based on no more than the definition of the determinant of a square matrix.

Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For any positive integer $j$ less than or equal to $n$, for any $n \times 1$ matrices $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{j+1}$, $\dots$, $a_n$, for any $n \times 1$ matrices $x$, $y$ and for any numbers $s$, $t$,
> $$ \begin{aligned}
>             & \det
>         {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, \overset{\text{column}\,j}{sx + ty},
>                     a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     \\
>     = {} &
>     s
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     +
>     t
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}.
> \end{aligned} $$

It will be proved that $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is true, which is left as an exercise.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true. It will be proved that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& B = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& C = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, sx + ty, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n].
\end{aligned}
$$
If $k \neq j$, then $[A]_{i,k} = [B]_{i,k} = [C]_{i,k}$. Hence $A(i|j) = B(i|j) = C(i|j)$. Note that $[C]_{i,j} = s[A]_{i,j} + t[B]_{i,j}$.

Suppose first that $j = 1$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(C)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} [C]_{i,1} \det {(C(i|1))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} (s[A]_{i,1} + t[B]_{i,1}) \det {(C(i|1))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(C(i|1))}
    }
    +
    t\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} [B]_{i,1} \det {(C(i|1))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}
    }
    +
    t\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+1} [B]_{i,1} \det {(B(i|1))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s \det{(A)} + t \det{(B)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Suppose then that $j > 1$. Note that for $\ell \neq j - 1$, column $\ell$ of $A(i|1)$, that of $B(i|1)$ and that of $C(i|1)$ are equal. Suppose that column $j-1$ of $A(i|1)$, that of $B(i|1)$ and that of $C(i|1)$ are $p$, $q$ and $r$, respectively. Then $r = sp + tq$. By the hypothesis, one has
$$
\det {(C(i|1))} = s\det {(A(i|1))} + t\det {(B(i|1))}.
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
         & \det {(C)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [C]_{i,1} \det {(C(i|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [C]_{i,1} (s\det {(A(i|1))} + t\det {(B(i|1))})}
    \\
    = {} &
    s \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [C]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}
    +
    t \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [C]_{i,1} \det {(B(i|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    s \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}
    +
    t \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{i+1} [B]_{i,1} \det {(B(i|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    s \det {(A)} + t \det {(B)}.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is direct, which is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about *any* column.

Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& B = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& C = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, sx + ty, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n].
\end{aligned}
$$
If $k \neq j$, then $[A]_{i,k} = [B]_{i,k} = [C]_{i,k}$. Hence $A(i|j) = B(i|j) = C(i|j)$. Since $[C]_{i,j} = s[A]_{i,j} + t[B]_{i,j}$, one has
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(C)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} [C]_{i,j} \det {(C(i|j))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} (s[A]_{i,j} + t[B]_{i,j}) \det {(C(i|j))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(C(i|j))}
    }
    +
    t\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} [B]_{i,j} \det {(C(i|j))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} [A]_{i,j} \det {(A(i|j))}
    }
    +
    t\sum_{i = 1}^{n} {
    (-1)^{i+j} [B]_{i,j} \det {(B(i|j))}
    }
    \\
    = {} &
    s \det{(A)} + t \det{(B)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first *row*. It is, however, surprisingly easier, compared with the one that is based on the definition (expansion about the first *column*).

Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For any positive integer $j$ less than or equal to $n$, for any $n \times 1$ matrices $a_1$, $\dots$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{j+1}$, $\dots$, $a_n$, for any $n \times 1$ matrices $x$, $y$ and for any numbers $s$, $t$,
> $$ \begin{aligned}
>             & \det
>         {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, \overset{\text{column}\,j}{sx + ty},
>                     a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     \\
>     = {} &
>     s
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}
>     +
>     t
>     \det {[a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n]}.
> \end{aligned} $$

It will be proved that $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is true, which is left as an exercise.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true. It will be proved that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, x, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& B = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, y, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n], \\
& C = [a_1, \dots, a_{j-1}, sx + ty, a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n].
\end{aligned}
$$
If $k \neq j$, then $[A]_{i,k} = [B]_{i,k} = [C]_{i,k}$. Hence $A(i|j) = B(i|j) = C(i|j)$. Note that $[C]_{i,j} = s[A]_{i,j} + t[B]_{i,j}$.

Let $k$ be a positive integer less than or equal to $n$, and unequal to $j$. Let $\ell$ be $j$ if $k < j$, or $j-1$ if $k > j$. Suppose that column $\ell$ of $A(1|k)$, that of $B(1|k)$ and that of $C(1|k)$ are $p$, $q$, $r$, respectively. Then $r = sp + tq$. By the hypothesis, one has
$$
\det {(C(1|k))} = s \det {(A(1|k))} + t \det {(B(1|k))}.
$$
Note that
$$
[C]_{1,j} = s[A]_{1,j} + t[B]_{1,j}.
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(C)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [C]_{1,k} \det {(C(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    (-1)^{1 + j} [C]_{1,j} \det {(C(1|j))}
    +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [C]_{1,k} \det {(C(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (-1)^{1 + j} (s[A]_{1,j} + t[B]_{1,j}) \det {(C(1|j))}
    \\
            &
    +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [C]_{1,k}
        (s \det {(A(1|k))} + t \det {(B(1|k))})}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    s (-1)^{1 + j} [A]_{1,j} \det {(C(1|j))}
    + t (-1)^{1 + j} [B]_{1,j} \det {(C(1|j))}
    \\
            &
    + s \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [C]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
            &
    + t \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [C]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    s (-1)^{1 + j} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(1|j))}
    + t (-1)^{1 + j} [B]_{1,j} \det {(B(1|j))}
    \\
            &
    + s \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
            &
    + t \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [B]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    s (-1)^{1 + j} [A]_{1,j} \det {(A(1|j))}
    + s \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
            &
    + t (-1)^{1 + j} [B]_{1,j} \det {(B(1|j))}
    + t \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\k \neq j}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [B]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    s \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    + t \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [B]_{1,k} \det {(B(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} & s \det {(A)} + t \det {(B)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.