# matrix: $\det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},u+v) = \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},u) + \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider a matrix $A_{n\times n}$ with real entries, denoted by $A=\left(A_{1}A_{2}\dotsm A_{n}\right)$, where $A_{i}$ represents the $i$th column of $A$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Suppose that the last column, $A_{n}$, is the sum of two vectors $u$ and $v$. Prove that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the sum of determinants obtained by replacing $A_{n}$ with $u$ and $v$ in the matrix:

$$
\det(A) = \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},u) + \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},v).
$$

I have generated numerous examples of varying sizes using online calculators, and this equality seems to hold true consistently. I managed to prove it for the cases of 2x2 and 3x3, but I genuinely have no idea how to demonstrate the general nxn case. Please help.

Comment: The proof depends upon the definition which you use. Maybe you can have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720976).

Comment: @Juliamisto I am considering the determinant of the matrix calculated using Gaussian elimination. I'm looking at the related post, but I understand that it's a more advanced topic than mine. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(x)_i$ denote the $i$-th component of $x$. Additionally, let $A_{ij}$ represent the cofactor associated with the entry $(i, j)$. Then,

\begin{align*}
\det(A) & = (u+v)_1 A_{1n} + (u+v)_2 A_{2n} + \dotsm + (u+v)_n A_{nn} \\
 & = (u)_1 A_{1n} + (u)_2 A_{2n} + \dotsm + (u)_n A_{nn} \\
 & \quad + (v)_1 A_{1n} + (v)_2 A_{2n} + \dotsm + (v)_n A_{nn} \\
 & = \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},u) + \det(A_{1},\dots,A_{n-1},v).
\end{align*}

This is using the method for calculating determinants known as the Rule of Laplace or the Cofactor Method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: I was not familiar with that method; I am just starting with determinants. I appreciate your response a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :)