# Prove the alternating property of the function $\det$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Suppose $A$ is a matrix. The $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is denoted as $[A]_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $m \times 1$ matrices. Then $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $(i, j)$-entry is equal to $[a_j]_{i,1}$. The piece of notation allows one to display a matrix using its columns.

*Determinants are defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712270/prove-that-the-determinant-of-a-square-matrix-can-be-computed-by-expansion-about).*

How does one prove the alternating property?

> Suppose that $q$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$. Suppose that $p$ is a positive integer less than $q$. Suppose that $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices. Suppose that $a_p = a_q$. Then
> $$ \det {[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]} = 0. $$

Let the proposition $P(n)$ be as follows:

> For any $n \times 1$ matrices $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$, any positive integer $q$ less than or equal to $n$, any positive integer $p$ less than $q$, that $a_p = q_q$ implies that
> $$ \det {[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]} = 0. $$

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true:
$$
\det {\begin{bmatrix}
    a & a \\
    b & b \\
\end{bmatrix}}
= ab - ba
= 0.
$$

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I need to show that $P(n)$ is true.

I know that it suffices to prove that the determinant of a square matrix with two *adjacent* equal columns is zero. Suppose that one has proved it. Using [the multilinear property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720976/prove-the-multilinear-property-of-the-function-det), one can prove that swapping two *adjacent* columns changes the sign of the determinant:
$$
\begin{align*}
    0
    = {} &
    \det {[\dots, \overset{\text{column}\,j}{b_j + b_{j+1}}, b_j + b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    \\
    = {} &
    \det {[\dots, b_j, b_j + b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    + \det {[\dots, b_{j+1}, b_j + b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (
    \det {[\dots, b_j, b_j, \dots]}
    +
    \det {[\dots, b_j, b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    )
    \\
    &
    +
    (
    \det {[\dots, b_{j+1}, b_j, \dots]}
    +
    \det {[\dots, b_{j+1}, b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    )
    \\
    = {} &
    \det {[\dots, b_j, b_{j+1}, \dots]}
    + \det {[\dots, b_{j+1}, b_j, \dots]},
\end{align*}
$$
in which $b_1$, $b_2$, $\dots$, $b_n$ are $n \times 1$ matrices.

Suppose that $p < q$. Suppose that column $p$ of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is equal to column $q$ of $A$. Let
$$
B = [\dots,
\overset{\text{column}\,p-1}{a_{p-1}},
\overset{\text{column}\,p}{a_{p+1}},
\dots,
a_{q-1},
\overset{\text{column}\,q-1}{a_p},
\overset{\text{column}\,q}{a_q},
a_{q+1},
\dots],
$$
which can be obtained from $A$ by swapping two adjacent columns $q-p\color{red}{{}-1}$ times. Hence
$$
0 = \det {(B)} = (-1)^{q-p\color{red}{{}-1}} \det {(A)},
$$
which means that $\det {(A)} = 0$.

However, I do not know how to prove the special case.

Comment: Could your number of column swaps carefully, we have to get there and back, which results in an odd number of swaps. For example, if you want to swap 1 and 3, then we have $abc \rightarrow BAc \rightarrow  b CA \rightarrow CBa $. It is not $ 3 - 1 + 1 = 2$ times.

Comment: @CalvinLin One does not have to get *back* here. (Because I did not want to *swap* the two equal columns.) Suppose that it has been proved that the determinant of a square matrix with two equal *adjacent* columns is zero. Suppose, for example, that columns $2$ and $5$ of $A$ are equal. One has $(1,2,3,4,5) \to (1,3,2,4,5) \to (1,3,4,2,5)$. The last matrix has two equal *adjacent* columns, so its determinant is zero. Hence $(-1)^{5-2\color{red}{{}-1}} \det {(A)} = 0$. (It is not $5 - 2 + 1$.) If one wants to prove the antisymmetric property, then it is necessary to get there **and back**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is direct, which is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about *any* column.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Choose a positive integer $q$ less than or equal to $n$. Choose a positive integer $q$ less than $p$. Suppose that column $p$ of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is equal to column $q$ of $A$.

**Choose a positive integer $u$ less than or equal to $n$ so that $u \neq p$ and that $u \neq q$.** Note that $A(i|u)$ has two equal columns (for $i = 1$, $2$, $\dots$, $n$). By the hypothesis, $\det {(A(i|u))} = 0$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+u} [A]_{i,u} \det {(A(i|u))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+u} [A]_{i,u} \,0}
    \\
    = {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof uses the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first two columns:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4721053) is a proof, which just uses the definition.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Let $A = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with two equal columns.

**As is mentioned in the description of the question, it suffices to prove the determinant of a square matrix with two *adjacent* equal columns is zero.**

Let $p$ be a positive integer less than $n$. Put $q = p + 1$. Let $[A]_{i,p} = [A]_{i,q}$.

Suppose first that $p > 1$. Then columns $p-1$, $p$ of $A(i|1)$ are equal. By the hypothesis, $\det {(A(i|1))} = 0$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \det {(A(i|1))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {(-1)^{i+1} [A]_{i,1} \,0}
    \\
    = {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Suppose then that $p = 1$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \det {(A)}
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,2} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,2} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {\det {
            \begin{bmatrix}
                [A]_{i,1} & [A]_{i,1} \\
                [A]_{k,1} & [A]_{k,1} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        (-1)^{i+k+1+2}
        \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{1 \leq i < k \leq n}
    {0\, (-1)^{i+k+1+2} \det {(A(i,k|1,2))}}
    \\
    = {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is based on the fact that the determinant of a square matrix can be computed by expansion about the first *row*.

I will prove that $P(n)$ (in the description of the question) is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$ by mathematical induction.

It is easy to check that $P(2)$ is true.

Suppose that $P(n-1)$ is true (in which $n \geq 3$). I will prove that $P(n)$ is true under the hypothesis.

Let $A = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with two equal columns.

**As is mentioned in the description of the question, it suffices to prove the determinant of a square matrix with two *adjacent* equal columns is zero.**

Let $p$ be a positive integer less than $n$. Put $q = p + 1$. Let $[A]_{i,p} = [A]_{i,q}$.

Note that $[A]_{1,p} = [A]_{1,p+1}$. Note that $A(1|p) = A(1|p+1)$. Note that for $\ell \neq p, p+1$, $A(1|\ell)$ has two equal columns. By the hypothesis, $\det {(A(1|\ell))} = 0$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & \det {(A)}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    + (-1)^{1 + p+1} [A]_{1,p+1} \det {(A(1|p+1))}
    \\
    & +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq p, p+1}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k} \det {(A(1|k))}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \hphantom{{} + {}}
    (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    + (-1)^{1 + p+1} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    \\
    & +
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n     \\k \neq p, p+1}}
    {(-1)^{1 + k} [A]_{1,k}\,0 }
    \\
    = {} &
    (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    - (-1)^{1 + p} [A]_{1,p} \det {(A(1|p))}
    \\
    = {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence by mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 2$, $3$, $\dots$.