# Why does $\det(A^2)= \det(A)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Question in Title.
Why does $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$? Old quiz answers gave this as a proof of why if matrix $A=A^2$, then $A=0$ or $1$.

Comment: **Hint:** What is $\det AB$? See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb and http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/DetMult.pdf

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is the factor by which the volume of any region is increased by the linear transformation represented by the matrix.