# if $\det(A) = 2$, what is $\det(A^3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What is the relationship between a determinant and the determinant of the same thing but to a power? 
Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb

Comment: Determinant is a multiplicative function on square matrices of the same dimension.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, we obtain: $$\det(A^3)=(\det(A))^3=8$$