# How the determinant of $A^2$ is $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $5\times5$ matrix and the dimension of the solution space of $Ax=0$ is at least $2$, then how $\operatorname{rank}(A^2) \le3, \space \det(A^2)=0$, I can't think what is the relation between $A^2$ and solution space. Thanks.

Comment: The determinant of a square matrix of order $\;n\times n\;$ is zero iff it is a singular matrix iff the dimension of the solution space of the corresponding homogeneous space is greater than zero... (and many more equivalence here...). And if a square matrix is singular, then all its powers are singular matrices, too. For example, by the product theorem for determinants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\operatorname{rank}(A)<5 \implies \det A=0$$ and by [**Binet theorem**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60284/505767)

$$\det(A^2)=\det A\cdot \det A=0$$

Comment: I did not get the point how the rank(A)< 5 @gimusi

Comment: @mystak Refer to [Rank-Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) for that.

Comment: ya i got it, i forgot to use it. thanks

Comment: @mystak That's really a foundamental fact, you need to do not forget that. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @gimusi, what is the meaning of 'dimension of the solution space of $Ax=0$ is at least 2.'

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod The set of all solution of $Ax=0$ is a subspace (why?) which is defined the **Nullspace of A** and then we can define a dimension for that in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the summation $\text{Rank}(A)$ and the dimension of the null space $N(A)$ is equal to the matrix dimension, we can conclude that $\text{Rank}(A)\leq3$. Since $\text{Rank}(AB)\leq \min\{\text{Rank}(A),\text{Rank}(B) \}$, we can easily prove  $\text{Rank}(A^2)\leq3%$. Since $A^2$ is also dimension 5, this gives out the singular property.