# Determinant of A transpose time B equals determinant of A times B transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am reading Franz Hohn's *Elementary Matrix Algebra* (1973) and having trouble solving the following exercise:

> Prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are both of order $n$,
>
> (a) $\det A^{T}B = \det A B^T = \det A^T B^T = \det AB$
>
> (b) $\det A^*B^* = \overline{\det AB}$.

My trouble is that the author has not yet proven the multiplicative property $\det AB = \det A \det B.$ If I could use that property (together with $\det A^T = \det A$ and $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$) then the exercise would be trivial. If I could get the first equality in (a) then I could get the rest of the problem.

While attempting to solve this exercise I ended up just proving the multiplicative property, but I don't think that's what the author intends. Am I missing something simple? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am fairly sure there is no proof simpler than just by proving the multiplicative property first.

Comment: You may be right, darij. I ask because this exercise comes before the section with the multiplicative property and it comes among a sea of other problems I was able to solve without the multiplicative property. It also seems like a strangely easy problem with the multiplicative property. I feel the author had something else in mind.

Comment: Which definition of determinant is given in the text?

Comment: determinants are defined via even and odd permutations

Comment: later, cofactors are defined and it is proven that a determinant has expressions in terms of cofactors

Answer (score 0):

We can use that $\det(C^T)=\det(C)$ and $\det(AB)=\det(BA)$ as follows:
$$
\det(A^TB)=\det(A^TB)^T=\det(B^TA)=\det(AB^T)
$$
At some point we need to prove the "classical" properties, like $\det(AB)=\det(BA)$ or even better, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. And then we do not care too much whether the text has it at page $xy$ or not.

Comment: Hmm, isn't $(A^T B)^T = B^T A$ and not $A B^T$? Or are you using another property, that $\det AB = \det BA$ (which also hasn't been stated or proved in the text)? Does that have a separate proof from the multiplicative property?

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering if there was a separate simpler proof of the equations in my question that didn't utilize det(AB) = det(A)det(B). But since I'm not getting an answer I'm guessing there probably isn't. It just seems like a misplaced exercise.

Comment: But I can't accept your answer since it doesn't really answer my question, which was to prove the equations without using the multiplicative property. But I think my question is a bad question that I never should have asked. It doesn't seem right to ask what the author's intent was.

Comment: Don't worry about acceptance. I think the best thing to do is to study the proof that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ holds somewhere else, e.g., at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb). Then your question is, as you said, a trivial consequence.

Comment: Thanks for your help! (I've already proved it myself and then three different proofs in the book by Hohn I mention in the question.)