# Inverse of a matrix — when is it defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I don't recall this well from linear algebra so I just need some quick confirmation.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and B is also $n \times n$ and $AB=I_n$ does it follow that also $BA=I_n$?

I think no but then what do we call inverse matrix: the left inverse, or the right one, or only when the left and right are the same we talk about inverse matrix of $A$?

Also, do we define inverse matrices of non-square matrices?

Comment: Yes, $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$. (when $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ matrices). So if a matrix is invertible from one side then it is invertible. For non square matrix we usually do not define an inverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

Comment: @AmanPandey Seems it does but the proof doesn't seem very simple. Isn't there some simpler proof?

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $\det{(AB)}=\det{(A)}\det{(B)}$ we can conclude that both $A$ and $B$ have non-zero determinants and hence are invertible. So we can write
\begin{align}
AB=I_n
&\iff A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}I_n\\
&\iff B=A^{-1}\\
&\iff BA=A^{-1}A\\
&\iff BA=I_n\\
\end{align}
So that a left inverse of any square matrix is also a right inverse and vice versa.

Comment: @peter.petrov [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb/60357) are some proofs of this fact.