# Determinant & Eignenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for an **intuitive** meaning of:

1)  Determinant of a Matrix

2) The implications of Eigenvalues and EigenVectors.

On example that really helped me from [betterexplained.com](http://betterexplained.com/articles/linear-algebra-guide/)

> The determinant is the “size” of the output transformation. If the
>   input was a unit vector (representing area or volume of 1), the
>   determinant is the size of the transformed area or volume. A
>   determinant of 0 means matrix is “destructive” and cannot be reversed
>   (similar to multiplying by zero: information was lost).
>
> The eigenvector and eigenvalue are the “axes” of the transformation.

Perhaps a practical example where these two concepts are applied would be really appreciated

Comment: It seems to me like the quote you give answers your first question. I'm not really sure what "the implications of eigenvalues and eigenvectors" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of determinant had been discussed multiple times on this site. See, e.g., the following threads:

- [What's an intuitive way to think about the determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668/1551)
- [What is the origin of the determinant in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194579/1551)
- [why determinant is volume of parallelepiped in any dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427528/1551)
- [Meaning of signed volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488163/1551)

Answer (score 1):

"impications" of eigenvectors /eigenvalues...for any linear function zero is a fixed point ( invariant under the function...if f is a linear function ..and..f(u) = ku ..for some number k...then the line through u and the origin (the vector subspace) is fixed under the function f.

Comment: apologies for recurrent typos..I need new glasses

Comment: You can use the "edit" feature to correct typos/improve formatting