# Development of geometric interpretations of ideas in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, math-history

I am curious as to how geometric intuition gradually developed in linear algebra. Are there articles that narrate how visualization became popular in this field? I think its important to know this as it might help us recognize the opportunity to do the same for other fields of mathematics when it arises.

Comment: Analytic geometry has shaped linear algebra a lot, see books with the title "Analytic geometry and Linear Algebra".

Comment: Geometry is much older than linear algebra.  The geometric ideas came first, and the linear algebra was developed with them in mind.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: does it tell how visualization crept into the field. From wikipedia, linear  algebra started with determinants. I can only imagine, probably, during the late 1800s up to the mid 1900s that linear algebra is mostly thought of in a very algebraic and formal manner with no reference to intuition. I am curious as to how geometric intuition developed from something that has little no relation to geometry...?

Comment: "no relation to geometry"? Determinants have a close relation, see volume.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: So linear algebra sprouted from analytic geometry?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Determinants have a close relation to geometry, I understand that. But what I meant that possibly, during its early stages of development that it possibly was not seen as closely related. I am curious as to how people connected determinant to the idea of area and volume in geometry.

Comment: It was, as Robert says, the other way around. The volume of a parallelepiped motivated the determinant, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194579/what-is-the-origin-of-the-determinant-in-linear-algebra).

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the link.

Comment: You might look at the Mactutor page [Matrices and Determinants](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Matrices_and_determinants.html)