# What is the meaning of the matrix determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

When studying linear algebra, you are constantly dealing with determinants. I read their definition on Wikipedia, saw all kinds of formulas, but found that if someone will ask me WHAT EXACTLY is a matrix determinant, I could not answer. All people who know math answered this question to me like this: "Well, this is such a thing, here is the formula to calculate it, it is very important in linear algebra." I understand that a determinant is the volume (or area) of a figure formed by vectors. I can’t understand why someone came up with the idea to use them. I realize that the question sounds like a request to explain the multiplication, and yet I ask it, since I am very curious about what a determinant really is.  If possible, answer as detailed and exhaustive as possible.

Comment: You should remove "If possible, answer as detailed and exhaustive as possible.".

Comment: There is a video of 3blue1brown on it, do check it on youtube

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of the determinant in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194579/what-is-the-origin-of-the-determinant-in-linear-algebra)

Comment: Counterintuitive answer:

http://www.axler.net/DwD.html

Perhaps if you could see all the ideas developed without determinants, it would allow you to step back and appreciate how the determinant connects the ideas.

Comment: Once answer to the question of "what is a determinant" is "it is an $n$-linear function on an $n$-dimensional vectors space, normalized so that $\det(I) = 1$".