# Why can't we define traces and determinants for non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading a book that claims that determinants and traces are only defined for square matrices, but doesn’t really explain why. 
From a calculation standpoint, this seems correct because I wouldn’t really know how to calculate the determinant of something like a column vector (with more than one row). However, the only justification I can think of is that using the meaning of a determinant, we’re trying to calculate the scaling factor of our unit cube, hypercube, whatever, while missing some “dimension” of it. I don’t really know if that makes sense, but it’s like if I were to ask you to find the volume of a box using only the dimensions of one of its faces. Is this a reasonable explanation, or is there a better reason why we can’t calculate the determinant of a non-square matrix ? And as for the trace, does that really just come down to the definition of the trace, or is there something more “meaningful” ?

Comment: I like your analogy

Comment: The problems we want to solve come first.  The definitions come after and are written in such a way as to be useful for solving the problems we want to solve.  In the case of determinants, one of the leading motivations was finding a way to determine whether or not a system of equations had a unique solution.  This was in the 1600's by Leibniz before matrices had even been developed yet.

Comment: Related: [What is the origin of the determinant in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194579/what-is-the-origin-of-the-determinant-in-linear-algebra).

Comment: Thinking in terms of eigenvalues, the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. Are eigenvalues/eigenvectors defined for non-square matrices?

Comment: Note that one can, in fact, find the (lower-dimensional) volume of the parallelopiped spanned by the columns of an $m \times n$ matrix with $m \geq n$. In particular: if $A$ is such a matrix, then this volume is given by $V = \sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$.

Comment: One possible line of justification is to take note of coordinate-free interpretations of determinant and trace that fail to generalize to "non-square" cases. For instance, the determinant can be seen as the unique $n$-linear alternating form on a dimension $n$ vector space, and the trace can be seen as the result of linearly extending the map $T:L(V) \to \mathbb F$ defined so that $T(vf(\cdot)) = f(v)$ for any $v \in V$ and $f:V \to \Bbb F$. Both of these interpretations require that the matrix in question be square.

Comment: If you want to define determinants for non-square matrices, you have to make a big compromise: since $\det(AB)$ in general is different from $\det(BA)$ when $A$ and $B$ are non-square, if $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are defined, one of the most important properties of determinant, namely, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, will no longer hold universally.

Comment: @user1551 Alternatively you can drop the requirement that the determinant be a real number, make the result of $\det$ non-commutative, and you can gain back the property that $\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$, and you actually get some really nice geometry out of it.