# Help with understanding the general formula for the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s an intuitive way to think about the determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant)

Could anyone give an intuitive explanation of the determinant? I know mostly what the determinant means and I can calculate it etc. But I have never got any real-world intuitive explanation of the general formula of the determinant?

How is the formula derived? Where does it come from? What I'm essentially asking is: Prove the general formula for calculating the determinant of an n-by-n matrix and explain the meaning of it

Any support = Thank you so much!! =)

Comment: In addition to the nice pointer by Mike S., you might also review http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81521/development-of-the-idea-of-the-determinant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's recall the basic properties of the determinant (which I assume in the following), thay seem to me very reasonable from a real world-point of view:

1. It is linear in each column, that is, for $1 \le i \le n$, $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in K^n$, $\lambda \in K$, $x_i' \in K^n$, we have
   $$
     \det (x_1, \ldots, x_i+\lambda x_i', \ldots, x_n) = \det(x_1, \ldots, x_n) + \lambda \det (x_1, \ldots, x_i', \ldots, x_n) $$
2. It is alternating, that is $\det(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$ if $x_i = x_j$ for some $i \ne j$.
3. $ \det(e_1, \ldots, e_n) = 1$.

We will use 1., 2. and 3. to derive the formula in what follows. So the intuitive explanation might be: If we want to calculate the volume of a general parallelepiped using only the standard cube and invariance properties, what do we get.

From 1. and 2. we can conclude, that changing two columns changes sign: 
\begin{align*}
 0 &= \det (x_1, \ldots, x_i + x_j, \ldots, x_i + x_j, \ldots, x_n)\\
   &= \det(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) + \det(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n)\\ & {} + \det(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) 
+ \det(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) \\
&= \det(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) + \det(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) \\
\iff \det(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) &= -\det(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)
\end{align*}
From this, writing a $\sigma \in S_n$ as a product of transpositions, one concludes by induction on the number of transpositions 
$$ \det(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}) = \mathrm{sgn}\, \sigma \cdot \det(x_1, \ldots, x_n) $$
For general $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in K^n$, we now start writing them in the standard basis (we want to use 3.), say $x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}e_i$. We have using multilinearity
\begin{align*}
  \det(x_1, \ldots, x_n) &= \det\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^n x_{i_11}e_{i_1}, \ldots, \sum_{i_n=1}^n x_{i_nn}e_{i_n}\right)\\
  &= \sum_{i_1=1}^n \cdots \sum_{i_n=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n x_{i_jj}\det(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_n})
\end{align*}
Now $\det(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_n})$ is by 2. different from zero only if $j \mapsto i_j$ is a permutation, so only $n!$ of the above $n^n$ summands remain, we get using what we found above for permutations
\begin{align*}
   \det(x_1, \ldots, x_n) &= \sum_{i_1=1}^n \cdots \sum_{i_n=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n x_{i_jj}\det(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_n})\\
   &= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \prod_{j=1}^n x_{\pi(j)j} \det(e_{\pi(1)}, \ldots, e_{\pi(n)})\\
   &= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \prod_{j=1}^n x_{\pi(j)j} \mathrm{sgn}\,\pi \cdot \det(e_1, \ldots, e_n)\\
   &= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}\,\pi \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n x_{\pi(j)j}
\end{align*}