# Determinants after Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, determinant, self-learning

I realize that Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is a great textbook, and the removal of determinants is often pedagogically sound. However, I was doing some problems on a practice entrance exam, and I was surprised by the amount of times solutions would involve having to apply determinants to geometric situations.

Therefore, my question is this:
Where I can learn more about determinants, preferably without having to relearn all of linear algebra from another textbook?

Comment: [Neil Strickland, *Linear mathematics for applications*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/19fla/MAS201.pdf) (Appendix B and Section 12) does the most important proofs really well. From there I'd move on to [Prasolov](https://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf) (Chapter I) and [Krattenthaler](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004).

Comment: Actually, you can learn a lot here at this site, just search after "determinants mathematics stackexchange". For example, one of the hits for me was [this nice post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81521/development-of-the-idea-of-the-determinant). I believe that there are several other interesting posts for you here, if you take the time to look them up.

Comment: You can just keep reading Axler. Chapter 10, and specifically section 10B, is about the determinant. It will be much more productive to see the construction of the determinant "done right" and formally than go back to an introductory material now that you already have the Linear Algebraic baggage. Axler has some "applications" (if you want to call them that) of determinatns to volumes, for example, at the end of the chapter, and also connections with positive operators (which relate to calculus), etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy introduction to determinants there are a lot of online resources. See for example

1. [Very basic intro to determinant](https://www.hec.ca/en/cams/help/topics/Matrix_determinants.pdf)
2. [Another intro to determinant with graphical representation](https://web.auburn.edu/holmerr/2660/Textbook/determinant-print.pdf)

For a very nice graphic representation have a look at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk).

Hope this helps!