# Geometrical Interpretation of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the geometrical Interpretation of a determinant?
I know a bit about the geometrical Interpretation of a matrix      but don't have any idea about this

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant).

Comment: [here as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250534/geometric-meaning-of-the-determinant-of-a-matrix). You could have found both these questions through a google search.