# Absolute Determinant: Geometric Argument

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Using a geometric argument, explain why the matrix below has maximal absolute determinant among all matrices with entires in {-1,1}.
>  
>   $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I believe this has something to do with the fact that each sub matrix is either a rotation or a reflection and there is a symmetric number of both. Does this thinking seem in line with others?

Comment: Check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250534/geometric-meaning-of-the-determinant-of-a-matrix

Comment: And this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant

Comment: Volume rather. See [this](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALAPP/Peng.pdf#page=5)

Comment: @ir7 Understood, but why does this specific matrix have maximal absolute determinant? Couldn't you find one with a different ordering that has a determinant of 16 as well?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a Hadamard matrix as its rows are mutually orthogonal. If you multiply it by its transpose you get the identity matrix times 4. Hence its determinant is $\pm 16$. You can then look up Hadamard’s maximal determinant problem to see why only these matrices can achieve the upper bound (maximum volume parallelotope).