# Determinant of unspecified matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose A and B are $5\times 5$ matrices with $\det(A) = -1/3$ and $\det(B) = 6$, find the determinant of $ 2AB$.

Solution:

$$= \det(2AB) $$
$$= 2^5 \det(A)\det(B) $$
$$= (32)(-1/3)(6)$$
$$= -64$$

---

I understand how all of this works, except for where $2^5$ comes from, can anyone explain how this happens?

Comment: You might want to check out Jamie Banks' answer to this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant).

Comment: Thanks for that link, very helpful!

Comment: I thought it's worth a read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you multiply a matrix by $2$, that multiplies all the rows of the matrix by $2$. The determinant is linear in each row, and the matrix $AB$ has five rows, so it multiplies the resulting determinant by $2^5$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $\, 2AB = (2I)AB,\,$ so $\det(2AB) = \det(2I) \det(A) \det(B).\,$ $\,2I\,$ is diagonal with fives $\,2$'s.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant is a **multilinear** form so 
$$\det(\lambda_1 C_1,\ldots,\lambda_n C_n)=\lambda_1\times\cdots\times\lambda_n \det(C_1,\ldots,C_n)$$

in your case take $\lambda_i=2,\quad i=1,\ldots,5$.