# Matrix rank and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given two matrices $A,B \in M_{4 \times 4} (\mathbb{R})$ such that $\det (AB) \ne 0$ what is the rank of the matrix B? How to solve this I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: use the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Thus the rank of b will be equal to 4?

Comment: I guess, but I can not really confirm. I think a determinant $\neq 0$ means that your matrix is of full rank but I am not entirely into determinants. Can some one else confirm or deny this?

Comment: @Pedro See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355644/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-determinant-equal-to-zero or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507638/intuition-behind-matrix-being-invertible-iff-determinant-is-non-zero (And probably several other posts on this site.) And maybe also [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_is_Invertible_iff_Determinant_has_Multiplicative_Inverse).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks! So the answer is 4, since the matrix is invertible and thus of full rank?

Comment: But am i right with the rank of B?

Comment: I guess it must be 4. Since you have only independent columns and the only solution in the nullspace of A = {0}, which means all your dimensions are part of your column space, and none of them are part of the null space. The number of independent columns is really what a rank of a matrix means. The more independent columns, the more "necessary dimensions" your matrix carries. Since all columns are needed to express the system, none of those columns can be expressed as a linear combination of te previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $AB$ is invertible, so has rank$~4$. The rank of a product of matrices can never be more than the rank of either of those matrices, so $B$ cannot have rank less than $4$. Now consider the size of $B$.