# Is the determinant the "only" group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^\times$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

This might be a dumb question; I know only enough group theory to be able to ask dumb questions.

Ken W. Smith has [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17610/856) that one way to get intuition about the determinant is to observe that it maps matrix multiplication to real multiplication. As it is continuous, too, this means that it is a Lie group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ to the multiplicative group of the nonzero reals, $\mathbb R^\times$. The natural question to ask, then, is whether it is the *only* such homomorphism.

Obviously not: any function $\mathbf A \mapsto (\det\mathbf A)^k$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ is also a homomorphism.

But are *all* homomorphisms between the two groups of such a form? That is,

> Is every Lie group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^\times$ identical to $\mathbf A \mapsto f(\det\mathbf A)$ for some homomorphism $f:\mathbb R^\times\to\mathbb R^\times$?

Comment: a Lie group homomorphism is determined by the corresponding Lie algebra homomorphism.  So what are all of the Lie algebra homomorphisms $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$?  These are the elements of the dual space of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R)$ that vanish on commutators.  Are multiples of the trace the only ones (the trace is the derivative of $\det$)?

Comment: @Eric: That sounds like a great question which I am completely unqualified to answer! However on Googling I found that [the commutator subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ is precisely $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb R)$](http://twoplusonet.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/commutator-subgroup-of-glnr/), which I assume is equivalent to the commutators of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R)$ being the traceless matrices. So the answer to both our questions is... yes, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how knowing that $SL$ is the commutator of $GL$ tells you that the trace is the unique form that vanishes on commutators.  You could probably prove this though using uniqueness of the Killing form on $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, if $\phi : G \to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism then we get a Lie algebra homomorphism $\phi_* :\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak h$.  If $\phi,\psi : G\to H$ are two Lie group homomorphisms then $\phi_* = \psi_*$ implies $\phi = \psi$.  So we really just have to classify Lie algebra homomorphisms $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ and then see which ones lift to the groups.

Since the Lie algebra $\mathbb R$ is abelian, these Lie algebra homomorphisms are those elements of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R)^*$ that vanish on commutators.  It turns out that this property uniquely characterizes the trace up to scale (I wasn't able to find a good reference for this but it should be easy, if a bit messy, to prove by hand).

So given $\phi : \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^\times$, we have $\phi_* = c \operatorname{tr}$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$.  Now $\phi_*$ restricts to the connected components where it integrates to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)_+ \ni A\mapsto(\det A)^c \in \mathbb R^+$.  Of course for this homomorphism to extend to all of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ requires that the map $a \mapsto a^c$ be well-defined on all of $\mathbb R^\times$ so Lie group homomorphism is $\det$ followed by an automorphism of $\mathbb R^\times$.

Comment: hi @Eric O. Korman it may be a stupid question but how can I prove that $\phi_*=\psi_*$ implies $\phi=\psi$? thanks

Answer (score 12):

Here's a more elementary proof, which has the advantage of not using the assumption that the homomorphism is continuous.  (It is a very minor adaptation of the proof of Theorem 3.2 in Cullen's *Matrices and Linear Transformations*, an early step in Cullen's axiomatic development of the determinant.)

Let $\varphi\colon \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}_\times$ be a group homomorphism.  Denote elementary matrices as follows:

1. $I_{kR_i}$ is the matrix obtained by multiplying the $i$th row of the identity matrix by $k$.
2. $I_{kR_i+R_j}$ is the matrix obtained by adding $k$ times the $i$ row of the identity matrix to the $j$th row.
3. $I_{R_i\leftrightarrow R_j}$ is the matrix obtained by exchanging the $i$th and $j$th rows of the identity matrix.

Let $i\colon\mathbb{R}_\times\to\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be defined by $i(x) = I_{xR_1}$.  Note that $i$ is a homomorphism.  We will show that, for all $A\in\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$ \varphi(A) = \varphi(i(\det(A))) \tag{$\ast$} $$
This establishes the desired result with $f=\varphi\circ i$.

First, ($\ast$) holds for $A=I_{xR_1}$, since then $A=i(\det(A))$.

Second, from the identity
$$ I_{kR_j} = I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j} I_{kR_1} I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j} $$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\varphi(I_{kR_j})
&= \varphi(I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j} I_{kR_1} I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j}) \\
&= \varphi(I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j} I_{R_1\leftrightarrow R_j} I_{kR_1})
    &&\text{(since $\mathbb{R}_\times$ is abelian)} \\
&= \varphi(I_{kR_1})
\end{align*}
which yields that ($\ast$) holds for elementary matrices of type 1.

Similarly, from the identity
$$ I_{kR_j+R_i} = I_{k^{-1}R_j} I_{1R_j+R_i} I_{kR_j} $$
we get $\varphi(I_{kR_j+R_i}) = \varphi(I_{1R_j+R_i})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$ (except $k=0$, which can be handled separately).  But since $I_{1R_j+R_i}^2=I_{2R_j+R_i}$, this yields $\varphi(I_{1R_j+R_i})=1$, whence $\varphi(I_{kR_j+R_i})=1$, verifying ($\ast$) for elementary matrices of type 2.

Similarly again, from the identity
$$ I_{R_i\leftrightarrow R_j} = I_{(-1)R_i} I_{1R_i+R_j} I_{(-1)R_j+R_i} I_{1R_i+R_j} $$
we get $\varphi(I_{R_i\leftrightarrow R_j}) = \varphi(i(-1))$, which establishes ($\ast$) for elementary matrices of type 3.

Finally, since elementary matrices generate $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, this establishes ($\ast$) for all invertible matrices.

Comment: Old post but I just want to say this is a lovely result. It's actually quite a strong statement. OP's function $f$ need not just be a homomorphism, but must also factor through $GL(n, K)$ in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : GL(n, K) \to K^\times$ be a homomorphism.

The subgroup of diagonal matrices is a product of $n$ copies of $GL(1) = K^\times$. The factors are conjugate within $GL(n)$ by swaps and hence $f$, being a homomorphism into an abelian group, acts identically on each factor. If $f' : K^\times \to K^\times$ is the restriction of $f$ to any such factor, we must have $f(\text{diag}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)) = f'(x_1) \cdots f'(x_n)$.

Every matrix in $GL(n)$ can be reduced to a diagonal matrix using only row operations where we subtract a multiple of one row from another. For a given pair of distinct rows i and j, we have a subgroup corresponding to these row operations. Let $E_k$ for $k \in K$ denote the subtraction of $k$ times the ith row from the jth row. For all nonzero $k, k' \in K$, the elements $E_k, E_{k'}$ are conjugate within $GL(n)$ via multiplication of the ith row by $k/k'$ and hence $f(E_k) = f(E_{k'})$ since $f$ is a homomorphism into an abelian group. Therefore $f$ on these subgroups is trivial: the row operations don't alter the value of $f$.

With this we've now reduced the problem to the $n = 1$ case, where the determinant is simply the identity function, so every $f$ in this case must be the composition of $\det$ with some endomorphism of $K^\times$.

When $K = \mathbb{R}$ the endomorphisms are the solutions to the classical functional equation $f(xy) = f(x) f(y)$. If we require continuity, these take the form $f(x) = f(\text{sign}(x)) |x|^a$ where $\text{sign} : K^\times \to \{+1, -1\}$ and $f(-1)$ can be $+1$ or $-1$.