# Are determinants the only surjective homomorphism from matrices to the reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, determinant, relations, group-homomorphism

Let $f: \mathbb R^{n^2} \to \mathbb R$, such that (i) $f$ is a surjection and (ii) $f$ is a homomorphism.

Clearly, $\det$ satisfies those conditions.  Is it unique? That is, is there another function, besides the determinant, from matrices to the reals that is a surjective homomorphism?

Comment: What does "homomorphism" mean in this context?  What algebraic structure are you trying to preserve? Can't be multiplication since you haven't required invertibility.

Comment: How is determinant a homomorphism?

Comment: @lulu But if the determinant is non-zero then it's an invertible matrix, isn't it? If the determinant is zero then it's similar to scalar multiplication. What did I get wrong here?

Comment: @SuzuHirose  The set of square matrices is not a group under multiplication, since inverses don't always exist.  Perhaps the OP meant to ask for homomorphisms from $\text {GL}_n(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R^*$ but that's not what is writtren.

Comment: If you intended to specify invertible matrices (and the non-zero reals under multiplication) then [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727050/is-the-determinant-the-only-group-homomorphism-from-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-r) is a duplicate.

Comment: There are exotic group isomorphisms $\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^*$, namely consider that $\Bbb R^*\cong C_2\times (0,\infty)\cong C_2\times\Bbb R\cong C_2\times\Bbb Q^{\oplus \Bbb R}$. Now take a $\Bbb Q$-linear bijection $T:\Bbb Q^{\oplus \Bbb R}\to \Bbb Q^{\oplus \Bbb R}$ and transfer the map $(x,v)\to (x,Tv)$ back along the chain of isomorphisms. Once you have $G:\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^*$ non-trivial isomorphism, extend it to the monoid $\Bbb R$ by sending $0\to 0$ (call it $\hat G$). Finally, $\hat G\circ \det$ is a second surjective whatever.

Comment: Also, obviously, $(\det(x))^3$.

Comment: @lulu I understand your point but $0$ isn't invertible under mulitplication so OP's meaning seems to be the case where the determinant is non-zero, $GL_n({\mathbf R})$ as you note. Also as you note this is then a duplicate. Thank you for responding.