# Area of an ellipse.

Tags: matrices

I need to find the area of the image of a circle centred at the origin with radius 3 under the transformation:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$

The image is the ellipse $ \frac{x^2}{81}+y^2=1$. It would appear that it has the same area as the original circle i.e. $9\pi$. Is this because the matrix has some special property such as being its own inverse?

Comment: This matrix is not its own inverse.

Comment: It's because the matrix has the property that its determinant is 1. By the way your equation doesn't match the matrix, perhaps the equation should be $x^2/9 + 9y^2=1$.

Comment: Think geometrically. You've stretched the $x$ axis and shrunk the $y$ axis.

Comment: Also by the way so you are clear - the matrix is not its own inverse.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out that it's not its own inverse. That was a big mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this matrix has a special property, namely its determinant is 1.

Comment: Is there a particular name or result for your answer?

Comment: May this question will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668/162363

Answer (score 0):

It is a known formula that the area enclosed in the ellipse with semi-axes $a$ and $b$ is $\pi ab$, as may be seen from the orthogonal affinity that transforms a circle into an ellipse.