# $2 \times 2$ determinants using cofactor expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354148/proving-the-formula-for-finding-the-determinant-of-a-square-matrix/1354164#1354164) already.

The definition of the determinant that is in this text I have is (for a $J \times J$ matrix $A = [A_{ij}]$):
$$|A| = \sum_{j=1}^{J}A_{ij}C_{ij}$$
where $C_{ij}$ is the cofactor of the cell $A_{ij}$ of the matrix $A$. For a $1 \times 1$ matrix $A = [a]$, $|A| = a$.

Let's suppose $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
The minors $M_{ij}$ are
$$\begin{align}
M_{11} &= [d] \\
M_{12} &= [c] \\
M_{21} &= [b] \\
M_{22} &= [a]\text{.}
\end{align}$$
The appropriate signs for the cofactors are 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
+ & - \\
- & +
\end{bmatrix}$$
so
$$\begin{align}
C_{11} &= +|M_{11}| = d \\
C_{12} &= -|M_{12}| = - c \\
C_{21} &= -|M_{21}| = -b \\
C_{22} &= +|M_{22}| = a\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$|A| = ad-bc-bc+ad = 2(ad-bc)$$
which I know is obviously wrong - this should be just $ad - bc$. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: When you do cofactor expansion you only need to expand along one row or one column, so you won't be actually using all four cofactors in your final answer

Comment: @RobBland AH, so the formula I have actually says to expand along a row. Thanks!

Comment: It should just be $aC_{11} + cC_{21} = a[d] - c[b] = ad - bc$ expanding along the first column, as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Rob Bland.

Expansion is done along the $i$th row using the definition in the question. So, for example, if $i = 1$,
$$|A| = A_{11}C_{11}+A_{12}C_{12}=ad-bc$$
as desired.

Expansion may also be done along a column as well, so alternatively, we may define 
$$|A| = \sum_{i=1}^{J}A_{ij}C_{ij}$$
for expansion along the $j$th column.

If we look at the first column for example,
$$|A| = A_{11}C_{11}+A_{21}C_{21}=ad-cb$$
agreeing with $|A|$ from expansion along the first row.