# What is the natural ( and historical) motivation for determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, math-history

I'm quite confortable with definitions such as a derivative or an integral because i get to see why they are the way they are and that feels really natural, there is a fundamental question to be solved such as "What is the slope at a certain point of the curve" and so on...  I can't see why someone would come up with the idea of a determinant, don't tell me that gives some area , I don't see why giving an area or a volume solves the kind of problems determinants do, is there a nice line of reasoning for determinants? Thank you guys !

Comment: You'll probably find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668/81360) and its answers helpful.

Comment: "Natural" is a rather subject term. Might be useful to add more information about what it really means.

Comment: I would like to know what was the fundamental problem one was trying to solve when came up with that tool.

Comment: Might be useful: [Historically, determinants were used long before matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#History)

Comment: They were originally used to tackle systems of linear equations.  One of the first important discoveries, if the determinant is zero, the system does not have a singular solution. Cramer's rule is an important step along the way.  The shoe-lace algorithm might be one of the early linkages of matrices to areas.

Comment: "Don't tell me that and that" is a nice invitation to think about an appropriate answer to such a grand view question.

Comment: this is a nice bit of history http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/Matrices_and_determinants.html