# Why is the volume of a parallelepiped linear in each row in the matrix representation?

Tags: matrices, determinant, volume

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant/669), the determinant of a matrix is explained to be a measure of the volume of a parallelepiped formed by using the columns in a matrix as vectors.

It is also noted that the determinant is linear in each row. We can represent this geometrically as the volume of a parallelpiped being the sum of the volumes of two other ones. Is there a geometric proof that the volume corresponding to these matrices is linear in this manner?

Comment: The determinant, by cinstruction, ismultilinear in its rows (or its columns as well), independently of any geometric consideration.

Comment: @Bernard: Sure, but it seems like there should be a geometric representation. Maybe I need to reword the question.

Comment: I think there is a geometric representation. Note that  the determinant does not change upon adding multiples of one row/column to another. This corresponds to a shear mapping of the paralelepiped, so the volume does not change under this operation. Then, you use the Gram-Schmidt process to express the original vectors which form the base,width and height (etc if there are more than 3 dimensions) in terms of a determinant which results from applying the operation of adding multiples of one row/column to another.