# Non-permutational Definition of the Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, determinant

I am looking for a non-permutational definition of determinant. The definition should have these properties:

1: Calculational power (easily applicable, it cold be used for practical calculations).

2: It should hold the usual properties (otherwise it wouldn't be a determinant, right!)

3: No permutation, No permutation, please no permutations.

I would also appreciate if you apply the definition and calculate the determinant of a $4×4$ matrix.

For all I care the definition could be from an obsolete parchment, but it needs to have those three properties.

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Alternating scalar valued tensor with value 1 at the point $(e_1,...,e_n)$. It is **equivalent** to the permutation definition, so there is no escaping it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want one like Liebniz' notation, but without the permutation.

Comment: You cannot escape the permutations.

Comment: Then take the Leibniz formula as in my answer. The permutations are not directly visible, but still in the background, like copper.hat says.

Comment: @copper.hat Nooo! may be its possible, let's see.

Comment: The determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal coefficients. For the general matrix, perform Gauss-Jordan reduction ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination ) till you get a triangular matrix, the determinant of each step being easy to compute. You may also want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant .

Comment: @Mindlack Hi, I know how to calculate determinants, but I was looking for a definition which has the positive aspect of being calculationally expressive.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost: At some level, permutations are the essence of the determinant... Being multlinear means there are potentially $2^n$ computations, by being alternating it reduces to $n!$. A smaller number means you are dealing with a special case (Hessenberg, triangular, etc.)

Comment: ...there is no escape.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for that input, but it has to be proven one way or the other. We can't just assume permutation are necessary. If you thinks so, then prove it. Tbh, I am not sure if it is necessary or not.

Comment: Let $A=P^{-1} LU$ be the partial pivot LU factorisation of $A$, then define $\det A = {1 \over \det P} \det L \det U$. Since $L,U$ are triangular, their determinants are just the product of the diagonal elements, and $\det P$ is just $(-1)^k$, where $k$ is the number of row exchanges performed while pivoting. This satisfies 1,3, but showing 2 would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $3\times 3$-determinant we can use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). Then
the $4\times 4$ determinant reduces to the $3\times 3$ determinant, because of
$${\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\\i&j&k&l\\m&n&o&p\end{vmatrix}}=a\,{\begin{vmatrix}f&g&h\\j&k&l\\n&o&p\end{vmatrix}}-b\,{\begin{vmatrix}e&g&h\\i&k&l\\m&o&p\end{vmatrix}}+c\,{\begin{vmatrix}e&f&h\\i&j&l\\m&n&p\end{vmatrix}}-d\,{\begin{vmatrix}e&f&g\\i&j&k\\m&n&o\end{vmatrix}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is not general. I need a general definition. The $4×4$ calculation was just so I can see how the def. Works when applied.

Comment: The general definition is, as already said, by the Weiserstrass axioms. From there $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$, $3\times 3$ are obvious. Then we also have $4\times 4$ from the above formula.