# Intuition behind integrating and differentiating determinants?

Tags: calculus

https://byjus.com/jee/differentiation-integration-of-determinants/

I saw this and I can't understand how this formula was derived, like why can we integrate row wise and add up determinants? Is there an intuition/ proof behind this?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668/721644).

Comment: what does that have to do with this

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: expanding 
$$
\det \left(
\begin{matrix}
f_1(x) & g_1(x) \\
f_2(x) & g_2(x)
\end{matrix}
\right) = f_1(x)g_2(x)-f_2(x)g_1(x)
$$
and differentiating,
$$f_1'(x)g_2(x)+f_1(x)g_2'(x)-f_2'(x)g_1(x)-f_2(x)g_1'(x),$$
you get the derivative of $\det \left(
\begin{matrix}
f_1(x) & g_1(x) \\
f_2(x) & g_2(x)
\end{matrix}
\right)$. You can rewrite the result as
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{matrix}
f_1'(x) & g_1'(x) \\
f_2(x) & g_2(x)
\end{matrix}
\right)+
\det \left(
\begin{matrix}
f_1(x) & g_1(x) \\
f_2'(x) & g_2'(x)
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
Use the same idea with integration.

Comment: hmm could you show how to do with integration also

Comment: You should try yourself. Just apply the definition of determinant and integrate.

Answer (score 0):

By the Laplace expansion formula, a determinant can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of a row (where the coefficients are the cofactors).

Hence by linearity of integration, you can integrate a row when the other rows are constants.

Comment: If you could explain with an example, I think it would be better