# Describing determinants of order $n$ as determinants of order $n-1$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm positive there's a sufficient answer for this here, but I can't seem to find it. I'd appreciate being redirected to the original question if anyone knows of one.

Take the augmented matrix below as an example, $$
\pmatrix{a_1 \ a_2 \ a_3 \\ b_1 \ b_2 \ b_3 \\ c_1\ c_2\ c_3}$$
Why is it that I am allowed to take the first component $a_1$, cover up every other element corresponding to its row and column, and multiply it to the remaining matrix $\pmatrix{b_1 \ b_3 \\ c_2 \ c_3}$, and then repeat this toward the last element on the first row? And why do the signs alternate? Like so:
$$a_1\pmatrix{b_2 \ b_3 \\ c_2 \ c_3}-a_2\pmatrix{b_1 \ b_3 \\ c_1 \ c_3}+a_3\pmatrix{b_1 \ b_2 \\ c_1 \ c_2}=$$

Comment: Read *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang. There's a chapter for determinant.

Comment: Maybe because it is defined like that.

Comment: @LalitTolani It can be defined in multiple ways, and other properties can be derived from it.

Comment: @seayellow, I agree with you "Laplace expansion " and "Leibniz Formula " are widely used to find determinants of a matrix. Interestingly we can find determinants using "Graph theory" also.

Comment: @ManishSaini Great stuff. Roger.

Comment: Try solving for $\vec{x}$. $$\pmatrix{a_{11} \ a_{12}  \\ a_{21} \ a_{22} }\vec{x} = \pmatrix{c_1\\c_2}$$ Then try it with bigger matrices and vectors. I think you'll see why determinants are defined the way they are.

Comment: @Lex_i You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668/81360) about the determinant helpful