# what is the geometric meaning of the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have come across a few definitions that describe the geometric meaning of the (absolute value) determinant, such as:

1. It is the area/ volume 'defined' by the column vectors of an n x n matrix
2. The amount that an area/volume is scaled with a linear transformation.

How is it that the determinant can mean both of those things?

Comment: Think about what the matrix does to the unit $n$-cube ... (e.g. if $n=2$ then I mean the square with vertices at $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's an intuitive way to think about the determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate; to address "how [can] the determinant mean both of those things?", the volume "defined by the columns of a square matrix" is the volume of the image of the unit cube, which is equal to the scale factor for volume of a linear transformation multiplied by the volume of the unit cube.